# Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I observed that when i use Logcat with Eclipse with ADT for Android, I get messages from many other applications as well. Is there a way to filter this and show only messages from my own application only.

Comment: All the answers suggest filtering for messages from the app being debugged. Even with these filters on, the Logcat spam from other apps soon fills the log buffer no matter how large it is. Is there a way to tell Eclipse to not collect these messages at all or to keep deleting them periodically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737594/1778421

Comment: https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/punt 
Try out this CLI tool - it makes filtering much easier.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Package names are guaranteed to be unique so you can **use the `Log` function with the tag as your package name and then filter by package name**:

*NOTE: As of Build Tools 21.0.3 this will no longer work as TAGS are restricted to 23 characters or less.*

`Log.<log level>("<your package name>", "message");`

`adb -d logcat <your package name>:<log level> *:S`

`-d` denotes an actual device and `-e` denotes an emulator. If there's more than 1 emulator running you can use `-s emulator-<emulator number>` (eg, `-s emulator-5558`)

Example: `adb -d logcat com.example.example:I *:S`

Or if you are using `System.out.print` to send messages to the log you can use `adb -d logcat System.out:I *:S` to show only calls to System.out.

You can find all the log levels and more info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

EDIT: Looks like I jumped the gun a little and just realized you were asking about logcat in Eclipse. What I posted above is for using logcat through adb from the command line. I'm not sure if the same filters transfer over into Eclipse.

Comment: I know the question was about eclipse, but I'm in love with command line and always use it for logcat as well.

Also use some tools for coloring the output like http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/ makes it even useful

Comment: Testing on emulator : it stuck for me when i execute adb -e logcat com.example.example:I *:S, adb -d logcat System.out:I *:S working.

Comment: @Shubh What do you mean it was stuck? I posted this almost a year ago so something in Logcat may have changed since then.

Comment: might be possible, but happening is when I execute " execute adb -e logcat com.example.example:I *:S" for my emulator it not respond anything, might be i am giving wrong argument.

Comment: @Shubh I just tested it on a device running 4.0.4 and a 2.3.3 emulator; worked fine in both cases. Are you sure the tag you're using is "com.example.example"? Such as `Log.i("com.example.example", "TESTING LOGGING")`. That adb command is correct.

Comment: This method filters by tag, not by app. Tom's method filters by app

Comment: @JonasAlves You should read the original question again. OP asked for a way to filter out log output from applications other than his own, which assigning a unique tag accomplishes. Tom's method below accomplishes the same thing, but uses a more roundabout method which won't help you if you want to use the Logcat GUI in Eclipse. This doesn't make the info in my answer any less relevant or correct.

Comment: I agree with Jonas comments. I am an beginner, and I am learning from a book. The book suggests to use a specific TAG for each Activity, and I believe most of others do so. As a result, it is a common question 'can I logcat by filtering with my package name, e.g. com.xxx.myapp', and I am actually looking for the solution that Tom provided. Thanks

Comment: @Flow Read the question and my answer again. The point was to set the logtag as the package name and then filter by that tag since the package name is guaranteed to be unique. If you read my answer more carefully you'll notice that I never claim to filter by package name. Take special note of the first edit.

Comment: By using `logcat <your package name>:<log level>` the answer suggests that it's possible to use the package name as valid filter.  I needed to read the answer twice to comprehend what it's actually saying, therefore I recommend to simply change the first line to something like "`logcat <tag>:<log level>` where `<tag>` can be your package name if you used also as tag in `android.util.Log`"

Comment: The answer doesn't answer the question; lots of times you'll want messages from libraries and you aren't able to change the tag.

Comment: This is not the good answer. Thanks for the comments here (highly rated) that clarify that this answer here is actually misleading. It is sad to see that this wrong answer got the highest ratings and approval, it shouldn't

Answer (score 468):

**Note: The following answer is over 10 years old. It's probably not the best answer anymore. My current preferred way of accomplishing this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/76551835/1292598**

### Linux and OS X

Use ps/grep/cut to grab the PID, then grep for logcat entries with that PID. Here's the command I use:

```bash
adb logcat | grep -F "`adb shell ps | grep com.asanayoga.asanarebel | tr -s [:space:] ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2`"
```

(You could improve the regex further to avoid the theoretical problem of unrelated log lines containing the same number, but it's never been an issue for me)

This also works when matching multiple processes.

### Windows

On Windows, to get full logs, you can do:

```bash
adb logcat | findstr com.example.package
```

Logcat logs has got levels at which to get info:

V — Verbose, D — Debug, I — Info, W — Warning, E — Error, F — Fatal, S — Silent

So to get only error logs related to the app, you can update the above command as follows:

```bash
adb logcat *:E | findstr com.example.package
```

Comment: How to use this command in windows?  specially the ` replacement in windows?

Comment: @BTRNaidu: You can install Cygwin or use git-bash (bash for windows)

Comment: Is there any way to do this programmatically within the Andorid app? I'm trying to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(THIS_COMMAND)` but it hangs the app.

Comment: What do all those parameters mean?

Comment: You can use this command if you want to get logs of your application just replace package-name with you app's package name         "pid=$(adb shell ps | grep "package-name" | cut -c10-15) && adb logcat | grep $pid"

Comment: `pid=$(adb shell ps | grep "package-name" | cut -c10-15) && adb logcat | grep $pid`

Comment: This works great when you have only one device plugged in, but unfortunately if you have > 1 android device plugged in, when you specify -s <deviceID> to adb, the command doesn't work.  Anyone know how to incorporate with adb -s?

Comment: I had to add "-a" to the `grep` command.  For some reason there was an occasional character that made `grep` think it was a binary file.  "-a" forces text-mode.

Comment: somtimes gc print the same number with pid number of a process when free memory. here is an another version `adb logcat | grep \`adb shell ps | grep org.videolan.vlc | awk '{print $2")"}'\``

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to include services and background tasks? I find they have different PID's than the actual application, yet Android Studio is able to capture full process-subprocess logs.  Not sure how to accommodate this.

Comment: On Windows you can do: `adb logcat | findstr com.example.package`

Comment: I don't know if it's by a different version of adb, or just by running on Windows, but I had to use `cut -c11-15`. Works perfect!

Comment: Just a minor change to your answer. I would suggest: ```adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | grep com.example.package | tr -s [:space:] ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2` ```

Comment: I think this is the only-really-working-command-line in all this ocean of answers.

Comment: As @hiepnd mentioned in his answer, I suggest to remove the double quotes since its not working for me, So the one-liner becomes for me: 



``adb logcat | grep -F `adb shell ps | grep com.example.app | cut -c10-15` ``

Comment: No solution based on grep will work, since it assumes messages are on a single line.

Comment: My version of this `adb logcat | grep -i \`adb shell ps | grep $1 | cut -c11-15\`` it's in a script and I just pass in the package name

Comment: The rare case where the windows example is simpler!!

Comment: My version: `adb logcat --pid=\`adb shell ps -o PID,Name | grep com.example.app | cut -d' ' -f1\``

Comment: @R. the `--pid` doesn't work if the program is not running at that moment. For example if you want to catch the crash of a program the PID only exists for a brief moment, you have to do it differently.

Comment: The `grep` or `findstr` approach doesn't work in most cases, since the debug info for a  package can be multi-line, and only the first (the title) will contain com.example.app.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this answer over 10 years ago. It was a reasonable approach at the time, but there are better mechanisms today. Personally, I use an alias that leverages the `--uid` flag, along with some `adb shell pm` magic to extract the correct uid.

Answer (score 195):

Since Android 7.0, logcat has --pid filter option, and pidof command is available, replace com.example.app to your package name.
(ubuntu terminal / Since Android 7.0)

```
adb logcat --pid=`adb shell pidof -s com.example.app`
```

or

```
adb logcat --pid=$(adb shell pidof -s com.example.app)
```

For more info about pidof command:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622698/7651532

Comment: I tried all the `grep` and `findstr` options, but they are only filtering logs with some value excluding a lot of messages. Your answer is the real one, show all log about the app without excluding log message from another libraries. It's like Android Studio current 'Show only selected' filter. Thanks!

Comment: These 2 commands work as long as process "com.example.app" is running. However, error messages will show up if the process is not running. Just a side note to avoid surprises.

Comment: The only answer here which actually works and does as the OP asked. Although, the OP did ask in '11 and things likely changed a lot in 6 years, but this answer still works in 2020.

Comment: @jonathanzh it works for me when the app is not "running". Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Oh I see, a completely not running app won't have a PID!

Comment: @Ben Butterworth: Correct. When an app is not running, it does not have a PID. As a result, typing the above commands may result in an output message: pid out of range.

Comment: If `pidof` exists on the device.

Comment: Best solution so far!

Comment: FOR /F %A IN ('adb shell pidof -s com.example.package') DO adb logcat --pid=%~A  
This is how I made it work on windows

Answer (score 56):

Add filter

[image: Add filter]

Specify names

[image]

Choose your filter.

[image]

Comment: It's quite important to be precise when you design development tools, since it's expected of the user to be precise. That's the package name, not the application name. >:(

Answer (score 54):

This works for me with USB debugging:

The solution was to use **your device's own logcat** directly via shell.

1. Connect the device and use:

   `adb shell`
2. Use logcat after the shell is set up:

   `logcat | grep com.yourapp.packagename`

Comment: this saved me so much time and trouble. very concise, right to the point. thanks!

Comment: This command will not show all the pid from the app, but only the logcat where it has your package name?

Comment: Yes. This one is basically a text filter, can be useful for system logs that are about your app, even if it's not running. If you need PID filter use other solutions.

Answer (score 20):

For me this works in mac `Terminal`
Got to the folder where you have `adb` then type below command in terminal

```
./adb logcat MyTAG:V AndroidRuntime:E *:S
```

Here it will filter all logs of `MyTAG` and `AndroidRuntime`

Comment: 1) Java code: `Log.d("MyTAG", "i am hero"); Log.d("AndroidRunTime", "i am zero");` 2) to DEBUG login to Android `$ adb -s RKSCWSOV5SAIEUSC shell;` 3) `$ logcat MyTAG:V AndroidRuntime:E *:S`  4) now it will show verbose of MyTAG and errors of AndroidRuntime

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on MacOS. Great job.

Comment: @om-ha thanks, I used Studio long time back and didn't know that it still has the issue

Comment: In fact I'm not using Android Studio.

I'm using Flutter, Android SDK, and Gradle.
As an editor, VS Code.
So this is an excellent way to know what's going on in my android phone

Answer (score 18):

```
adb logcat -e "package-name"
```

This works prefectly when filtering rows for one app only.

Answer (score 13):

## Update May 17

It's been a few years, and thing have changed. And Eclipse is no longer officially supported. So here's two more up-to-date approaches:

#### 1. Android Studio

[image]
In the `Android monitor` toolbox, you can filter logcat per `debuggable process`. Normally, when you develop an application it is a debuggable process. Every once in a while I am having issues with this, and a do the following:

1. `Tools` -> `Android` -> `Enable ADB Integration`. 
   If it was already enabled, then toggle it off, and then back on
2. Unplug and replug your mobile device.

There are also options to filter via regex and the debug level

### 2. [logcat-color](https://github.com/marshall/logcat-color)

This is a nice python wrapper on top of `adb logcat` if you want to use a terminal based solution. The good thing about it is that you can save multiple configurations and simply reuse them. Filtering by `tags` is quite reliable. You can also filter by `package` to see logs of one or more apps only, but you start `logcat-color` right before launching your app.

## Old Answer:

It seems that I can't comment to previous answers, so I will post a new one.
This is a comment to **Tom Mulcahy**'s answer, that shows how the command should change so as to work on most devices, since `adb shell ps` PID column is variable.

**NOTE:** The command below works for the cases where you have connected many devices. So `device id` is needed. Otherwise, you can simply omit the brackets '[', ']'

**1. To find out the column of pid, type:**

```
adb [-s DEVICE_ID] shell ps | head -n 1
```

Now memorise the column number for the PID. Numbering starts from `1`.

**2. Then type the following:**

```
adb [-s DEVICE_ID] logcat | grep $(adb [-s DEVICE_ID] shell ps \
| grep "com.example" | awk -F" " ' {print $PUT_COLUMN_HERE}')
```

Simply put the column you memorised in `PUT_COLUMN_HERE`, e.g. `$5`

#### Caveat

Each time you re-run your application, you have to re-run the 2nd command, because the application gets a new PID from the OS.

Comment: Look at all these things you have to do just to get logs for your app, not other apps. Plus, I really find it ridiculous that other people can see other people's logs. Are you telling me that there is nothing Google can do about it? Just make sure my logs are not seen by other people, and keep my logcat clean?

Answer (score 12):

Ubuntu :  **adb logcat -b all -v color --pid=`adb shell pidof -s com.packagename`** With color and continous log of app

Comment: The `adb shell pidof ...` bit didn't work for me so I `adb shell` ed into the device and ran `top` copied the PID for my app there and then replaced it in your command

Comment: try `pgrep` instead of pidof

Comment: This works for me on OSX, extra points for -v color

Answer (score 11):

This has been working for me in git bash:

```
$ pid=$(adb shell ps | grep <package name> | cut -c11-15) ; adb logcat | grep $pid
```

Answer (score 9):

put this to applog.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
PACKAGE=$1
APPPID=`adb -d shell ps | grep "${PACKAGE}" | cut -c10-15 | sed -e 's/ //g'`
adb -d logcat -v long \
 | tr -d '\r' | sed -e '/^\[.*\]/ {N; s/\n/ /}' | grep -v '^$' \
 | grep " ${APPPID}:"
```

then:
`applog.sh com.example.my.package`

Comment: Here's a variation of the filter to capture multiline logs (if you've done `log.d("TAG", "multine\nlog")` for example): `adb -d logcat -v long | sed -Ene '/^\[.*'" (${APPID}):"'.*\]/ { N; s/\n/ /; p; :a;' -e 'n; p; s/^.+$/foo/; t a;' -e ' }' | grep -v '^$'` - I left out the `tr`, I'm assuming it's needed on Windows systems, and I wrapped the `APPID` in parentheses to allow mulitple pids (separated by `|`).

Answer (score 8):

Using Windows command prompt: `adb logcat -d | findstr <package>`.

*This was first mentioned by [jj_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988591/jj), but it took me ages to find it in the comments...

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **Android Studio** you can select the process from which you want to receive logcats. 
Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: as from android studio ver 0.4.5 u will get messages from the app that is running only. 

`Log cat has a new option (on by default) which creates an application filter automatically such that only the launched application's output is shown`

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a shell script for filtering logcat by package name, which I think is more reliable than using

```
ps | grep com.example.package | cut -c10-15
```

It uses /proc/$pid/cmdline to find out the actual pid, then do a grep on logcat

https://gist.github.com/kevinxucs/7340e1b1dd2239a2b04a

Answer (score 7):

**Use `-s` !**

> You should use your own tag, look at:
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html
>
> Like.
>
> ```
> Log.d("AlexeysActivity","what you want to log");
> ```
>
> And then when you want to read the log use>
>
> ```
> adb logcat -s AlexeysActivity
> ```
>
> That filters out everything that doesn't use the same tag.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537430/2227298)

Comment: Don't assume you're writing the code.  You may care about messages from libraries, and you can't change the log strings.

Answer (score 7):

**LogCat Application messages**

As a variant you can use third party script [PID Cat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) by Jake Wharton. This script has two major advantages:

- shows log entries for processes from a specific application package
- color logcat

From documentation:

> During application development you often want to only display log messages coming from your app. Unfortunately, because the process ID changes every time you deploy to the phone it becomes a challenge to grep for the right thing.
>
> This script solves that problem by filtering by application package.

An output looks like
[image]

Answer (score 6):

ADT v15 for Eclipse let you specify an application name (which is actually the package value in your androidmanifest.xml).

I love being able to filter by app, but the new logcat has a bug with the autoscroll.  When you scroll up a little to look at previous logs, it automatically scrolls back to the bottom in a couple seconds.  It seems scrolling 1/2 way up the log does keep it from jumping back to the bottom, but that's often useless.

EDIT: I tried specifying an app filter from the command-line -- but no luck.  If someone figures this out OR how to stop the autoscroll, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

In order to access the logcats you first need to install ADB command-line tool. ADB command-line tool is a part of android studio platform tools and can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools). After this, you need to set the path/environment [variable](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables) for adb tools. Now you can access logcat from eclipse terminal/ intellij terminal or mac terminal in case you are using a macbook.

`adb logcat` : To get entire logcat.

`adb shell pidof 'com.example.debug'` : To get the process id of your app.

`adb logcat pid=<pid>` : To get logcat specific to your app.

`adb logcat pid=<pid>|grep 'sometext'` : To filter logcat on basis of some text.

For more info about filtering logcats read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat).

Comment: This answer should work, but it doesn't for me. `logcat` just keeps spitting out every log message from every app.

Comment: it should be `adb logcat --pid=<pid>`. you should be able to do `adb logcat --pid=$(adb shell pidof <package name>)`

Answer (score 6):

For a debuggable application, I suggest

```
adb shell run-as my.package.name logcat
```

run-as doesn't work for non-debuggable applications, so for those I use the `--uid` flag. Unfortunately there isn't a `uidof`, so I need to extract it from `pm`. Here's a small sh script to do that:

```
function logcat {
  pkg="$1"
  shift
  if [ -z "$pkg" ]; then
    >&2 echo 'Usage: logcat pkg ...'
    return 1
  fi

  uid="$(adb shell pm list package -U $pkg | sed 's/.*uid://')"
  if [ -z "$uid" ]; then
    >&2 echo "pkg '$pkg' not found"
    return 1
  fi

  adb logcat --uid="$uid" "$@"
}
```

Usage is `logcat my.package.name`. It accepts additional arguments like normal logcat.

I prefer this to the `--pidof` based solution (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004086/1292598) since that requires you to re-run the command each time the process is restarted.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10, using Ionic, what worked great to me was combine 'findstr' with the "INFO:CONSOLE" generated by all App messages. 
So, my command in command line is:

```
adb logcat | findstr INFO:CONSOLE
```

Answer (score 3):

I am usually adding something in the log messages to make it distinct. Or for example unity app you can use "Unity" as matching string.

For mac :

```
adb logcat | grep "MyUniqueString"
```

for Windows (powershell ):

```
adb logcat | Select-String "MyUniqueString"
```

Comment: `grep` implementation helped a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I have different approach, you can try access to local device's shell.

`adb shell`

and then follow by

`logcat | grep com.package.name`

This print all containing that package.

Alternatively, You can try `flutter logs --verbose`

Answer (score 3):

Another way of getting logs of exact package name when you are inside the shell:

```
logcat --pid $(ps -ef | grep -E "com.example.app\$" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a way to only see system messages regarding your app, but you can filter based on a string.  If you're doing a log within the program, you can just include a certain unique keyword, and filter based on that word.

Answer (score 2):

Try: Window -> Preferences -> Android -> LogCat. Change field "Show logcat view if ..." the value "VERBOSE". It helped me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Eclipse**, press the **green + sign** in the **logCat** window below and put your package name (com.example.yourappname) in the **by Application Name** box. Also, choose any name comfortable to you in **Filter Name** box and click ok. You will see only messages related to your application when the filter you just added is chosen from the left pane in the logCat.

Answer (score 2):

Give your log a name. I called mine "wawa".

[image]

In Android Studio, go to Android-> Edit Filter Configurations

[image]

Then type in the name you gave the logs. In my case, it's called "wawa". Here are some examples of the types of filters you can do. You can filter by System.out, System.err, Logs, or package names:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the simplest solution.

On top of a solution from Tom Mulcahy, you can further simplify it like below:

```
alias logcat="adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | egrep '\bcom.your.package.name\b' | cut -c10-15`"
```

Usage is easy as normal alias. Just type the command in your shell:

```
logcat
```

The alias setup makes it handy. And the regex makes it robust for multi-process apps, assuming you care about the main process only.

Of coz you can set more aliases for each process as you please. Or use hegazy's solution. :)

In addition, if you want to set logging levels, it is

```
alias logcat-w="adb logcat *:W | grep `adb shell ps | egrep '\bcom.your.package.name\b' | cut -c10-15`"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below command to fetch verbose logs for your application package

adb logcat com.example.myapp:V *:S

Also if you have rolled out your app and you want to fetch error logs from released app, you can use below command.

adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use Tom Mulcahy's answer but unfortunately it was not working for applications with multiple processes so I edit it to fit my needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then echo "Illegal number of parameters"; exit 1; fi
echo "Lof for package name: $1"
PROCESSES=`adb shell ps | grep "$1" | cut -c10-15`
NUM_OF_PROCESSES=`echo "$PROCESSES" | wc -l`
if [ $NUM_OF_PROCESSES -eq 0 ]; then echo "The application is not running!"; exit 1; fi
COUNTER=1
for process in $PROCESSES; do
        if [ $COUNTER -eq 1 ]; then GREP_TEXT="("; fi
        GREP_TEXT+=$process
        if [ $COUNTER -eq $NUM_OF_PROCESSES ]; then GREP_TEXT+=")"; else GREP_TEXT+="|"; fi
        let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
        if [ $COUNTER -gt $NUM_OF_PROCESSES ]; then break; fi  
done
adb logcat | grep -E "$GREP_TEXT"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **Tom Mulcahy**'s answer, if you want to filter by PID on Windows' console, you can create a little batch file like that:

```batch
@ECHO OFF

:: find the process id of our app (2nd token)
FOR /F "tokens=1-2" %%A IN ('adb shell ps ^| findstr com.example.my.package') DO SET PID=%%B

:: run logcat and filter the output by PID
adb logcat | findstr %PID%
```

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a question aimed at usage of Logcat from *outside* of the developer device, however if you want to display Logcat output *on* the device (programmatically), you just need this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat " + android.os.Process.myPid() + " *:D");
```

The `*:D` at the end filters out every message below Debug log level but you can leave that out.

To direct the output to, say, a TextView, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application).

Answer (score 1):

For windows, you can use my PowerShell script to show messages for your app only:
https://github.com/AlShevelev/power_shell_logcat

Answer (score 0):

Now is possible to type tag:nameofthetag or app:nameoftheapp to filter without adding new filters to the saved filters bar

Answer (score 0):

In intelliJ (and probably in eclipse also) you can filter the logcat output by text **webview**, so it prints basically everything phonegap is producing

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant of Gavriel's `applog.sh` with support of several devices and applications with multiple processes:

```
#!/bin/sh
PKG=$1
shift

APPIDS=`adb $@ shell ps | awk -v PKG="$PKG" '
    (NR == 1){appcolumn=2; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="PID") {appcolumn=i}}
    index($0,PKG){print $(appcolumn)}' | paste -d \| -s`

echo "PID's: $APPIDS"
adb $@ logcat -v color | awk  "(\$3 ~ /$APPIDS/){print \$0}"
```

Usage: `applog.sh com.example.my.package [-s <specific device>]`

Answer (score 0):

**Windows CMD**

For sample, if your application package name is: ***com.nader.chat***

```
cd C:\Users\[your-username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
adb shell logcat *:E | findstr /c:"at com.nader.chat"
```

[image]

- **:E** just filter Erros from logs, you can replace it with ***V**: Verbose (lowest priority)*, ***D**: Debug*, ***I**: Info*, ***W**: Warning*, ***F**: Fatal*.
- **at** to find errors just in your written source code not for others related modules

Answer (score -2):

In linux, this worked for me:

```bash
adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | grep your.package | awk '{print $2}'`
```