# Can IDEA's logcat filter automatically recognize running app?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Either I am unable to find this or IDEA **still hasn't** implemented the smart filter like Eclipse did long time ago.

When I am looking at `logcat` tab in IDEA 11, I do not see that it automatically recognizes running app and adds it under `All Messages`, just like Eclise does for each runnung app.

Am I missing something?

I saw that they added "Improved Filtering" feature a year ago ([link](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/11/new-in-intellij-idea-11-improved-filtering-in-android-logcat/)), but I still haven't found a good use of it. Have you?

Comment: I use application tag filter as described in the blog.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is there a topic where we can support creating of feature I mentioned?

Comment: You can submit requests at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Have you come across anyone posting this feature before? So that I can vote to that topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter Android logcat by application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537419/how-to-filter-android-logcat-by-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not available yet. I've [added a new feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95780), feel free to vote.