# Filtering Logcat Logs on commandline

Tags: android, logcat

```
public static final TAG = "Legendry Eagle";
```

Issue:  I want to see logs of `"Legendry Eagle"` from the commandline.

I tried:

```
 adb logcat -s "Legendry Eagle" 
 adb logcat -s <Legendry Eagle>
```

But Still it is not working.

Comment: Offtopic: Why are you using DOS Promt, and not Eclipse for debugging? Or are you not debugging?

Comment: use [this][1] link, it may be helpful


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537419/how-to-filter-android-logcat-by-application

Comment: Are you sure you are not simply misspelling the tag on the command?  Maybe your project actually uses _Legendary Eagle_, but you are searching for _Legendry Eagle_ (or vice versa).

Comment: Docs say `The series of specifications is whitespace-delimited.` so you can't use a space in the tag if you're trying to filter by it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you only want to show logcat for a specific TAG, do it like this:

```
adb logcat YourTAGHere:Priority *:S
```

The `*:S` is important, as it sets all other tags to silent. If I want to track only my `MainActivity` tag at Verbose level, the syntax would look like this.

```
adb logcat MainActivity:V *:S
```

**Edit:**
I found no good way of filtering out tags with spaces. `LegendryEagle` works fine, but I was not able to filter out `Legendry Eagle`

Comment: Docs say `The series of specifications is whitespace-delimited.` which is probably why his "Legendry Eagle" tag was failing to filter.

Comment: +1 for the *:S. It really makes clear for me now how to use options

Comment: `The series of specifications is whitespace-delimited` because you're on the Windows command prompt,  and when you're on the Windows command prompt, you can surround whitespace-using parameters with double quotes i.e. `"White Space Parameter"` to escape them.  Think about `move "c:\android files" "c:\my code\android files"`. This means you should be able to do: `adb logcat "Legendary Eagle:Priority" *:S`.  I cannot confirm exactly as I don't have any whitespace-using tags to test with, but this worked:  `adb logcat "StatusBarManagerService:V" *:S` so that tells me it's on Windows and not adb.

Comment: @NeptuneSystems Even with double quotes only the first word is used by adb to filter the output. [Aleks G's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931729/filtering-logcat-logs-on-commandline/13932016#13932016) provides a solution if you want to filter strings containing whitespaces.

Comment: >The *:S is important, as it sets all other tags to silent

+1 thx a lot!

Comment: You can use the -s option instead of *:S, in this case this would be "adb logcat -s MainActivity:V".

Answer (score 22):

If the standard `adb logcat -s tagname` doesn't work, you can always pipe the output of `adb` to `find` to filter what you need, something like

```
adb logcat | find "Legendry Eagle"
```

This passes the entire logcat to DOS `find` command, which in turn filters out rows containing *Legendry Eagle* string.

Comment: the extension with 'find xyz' solved my problem too, thx! (that's the minimal bit the internet won't tell you unless you perform a full 1-hour-research)

Comment: This solved my problem. The *:S and -s approaches might be outdated.

Answer (score 15):

```
adb logcat | grep "your tag"
```

will only display logs with "your tag"

Answer (score 5):

Answer is very simple . Please remove space between two words and try again.

```
 public static final TAG = "LegendryEagle";
 adb logcat -s "LegendryEagle"
```

and see the logcat . You got your answer.

Comment: The web view log all `console.log` to "Web Console", so this does not really help.

Answer (score 2):

use this command adb logcat *:W and read this. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Eagle as the logging tag, use this:

> adb logcat Eagle:* *:s

as I understand the Eagle:* means to turn on all logs for the Eagle tag, and the *:s means to make all other tags silent

I personally find the eclipse logcat view much easier to use than the command line, it has different colors for different levels of logs, and you can create a filter and save it, it'll stay there forever until you delete that filter