# How to log errors that only belong to a specific app?

Tags: android, windows, unix, adb, logcat

I want to log error messages of my own app by using logcat, similar to how I can do it on Unix, like

```
adb logcat *:E | grep com.example.demo
```

My question is:

**1.how to make it on windows?**

**2.Is there a way can be used in both platform(unix and windows) easily?**

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: windows or linux, its the same command. just make sure your adb is in your [environment path](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: As you can see,to achieve my goal,I use grep,it's a unix command,not in adb command,so I can't use it on windows also.

Comment: sorry i didn't see the grep command. you can filter it using this `adb logcat com.example.example:I *:S`

Comment: but `com.example.demo` is my package name,not my log tag.

Comment: hem.. replace grep with find in windows?

Comment: I believe this answers your Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931729/filtering-logcat-logs-on-commandline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all gave efforts to this question,I think I have found method to solve this,

On unix:

```
adb logcat *:E | grep com.example.demo
```

On Windows:

```
adb logcat *:E | find "com.example.demo"
```

Answer (score 2):

The grep command is available in Android shell. You could use it instead and it will work on both Windows and Linux.

```
adb shell "logcat *:E | grep com.example.demo"
```