# Adding a filter to log output in cmd

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I'm using

> adb -s [deviceId] logcat

to print the device's log output into cmd. But now I want to add a TAG filter to the shown output. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -s option.

```
          adb logcat -s MyActivity
```

Drawing from the link @ [How to filter Android logcat by application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537419/how-to-filter-android-logcat-by-application)

For list of options check the link below

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

For tagging check the below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: yes I found sth similiar, but I dont know how to combine both commands?
'adb -s [deviceId] logcat'  and ' adb logcat -s MyActivity'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> adb logcat | findstr MyActivity

findstr is 'grep' in Windows. 
filter anything you want than.