# Intent in action bar not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar, uncaught-exception

I have two activities with two layouts and a action bar. 
The minimum API I am using is 14.
I go from one activity to another with no problem using intent, and I want to make a home button in the action bar to return to the activity that I choose.
I implemented a menu and called it from xml using the guides on the android developers site, but when I click on the button/menu from the action bar, it crashes with uncaught exception.

**The main activity class:**

```
         package com.example.quiz;

         import android.app.ActionBar;
         import android.app.Activity;
         import android.content.Intent;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.view.Menu;
         import android.view.MenuInflater;
         import android.view.MenuItem;
         import android.view.View;
         import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
         import android.widget.Button;

         public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button new_b;
     ActionBar actionBar;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();


         new_b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.new_button);

         new_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override   
         public void onClick(View v) { 

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        };
          });   

         }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home_button:homeClick();
                return true;
            case R.id.info_button:homeClick();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);                   
        }           
     }

     private void homeClick() {
        Intent intent_home = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
        intent_home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent_home);     
     }
        }
       }
```

**The home activity class:**

```
         import android.app.ActionBar;
         import android.app.Activity;
         import android.content.Intent;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.view.Menu;
         import android.view.MenuInflater;
         import android.view.MenuItem;

         public class HomeActivity extends Activity {   

     ActionBar actionBar;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home_button:homeClick();
                return true;
            case R.id.info_button:homeClick();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);                
        }

     }

     private void homeClick() {
        Intent intent_home = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
        intent_home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent_home);    
      }
         }
        }
```

**Can I make it another way, or what can I do to make it work?**

```
           04-20 19:31:57.610: I/Adreno200-EGL(5708): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:
           AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL3357771_release_AU (CL3357771)
           04-20 19:31:57.610: I/Adreno200-EGL(5708): Build Date: 02/25/13 Mon
           04-20 19:31:57.610: I/Adreno200-EGL(5708): Local Branch: 
           04-20 19:31:57.610: I/Adreno200-EGL(5708): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
           04-20 19:31:57.610: I/Adreno200-EGL(5708): Local Patches: NONE
           04-20 19:31:57.610: I/Adreno200-EGL(5708): Reconstruct Branch AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107 +  NOTHING
           04-20 19:31:57.850: W/ResourceType(5708): getEntry failing because entryIndex 14 is beyond type entryCount 1
           04-20 19:31:57.850: W/ResourceType(5708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000e (t=10 e=14) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
           04-20 19:32:09.390: E/dalvikvm(5708): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2965K, 22% free 12424K/15751K, paused 12ms+26ms, total 75ms
           04-20 19:32:10.600: W/dalvikvm(5708): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d02438)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was trying to format my strings with html code.

Example:

**I was using:**

```
    <string name="title"> <b>App title</b> </string>
```

When I was supposed to use:

```
    <string name="title"> App title <string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as an example:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.quiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.go_home:
                Intent intentHome = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentHome);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**/res/menu/activity_main_actions.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/go_home"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/go_home" />

</menu>
```

Comment: @Eduard Do you use Eclipse? Can you provide logcat output?

Comment: Yes, I am using Eclipse and I provided the logcat output that I get.

Comment: @Eduard It looks like this logcat output has nothing to do with your application. It is not related to your code. The right output should show more lines with names of your classes. You should run your application and filter the logcat output for your package name for instance. This could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/21559617/3343299

Comment: Thank you for your interest and support!