# TestFairy: No logs from logcat during sessions of particular users

Tags: android, testing, logcat, testfairy

We are currently using TestFairy to let testers test our app. Unfortunately in the case of one of them the logcat logs recording isn't working and the only logs which you can see are something like that:

```
00:02 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: mobileapp.xxx.com get result from proxy >>
00:02 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: mobileapp.xxx.com get result from proxy >>
00:07 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: collector-5.testfairy.com get result from proxy >>
00:11 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: collector-5.testfairy.com get result from proxy >>
00:14 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: collector-5.testfairy.com get result from proxy >>
00:18 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: collector-5.testfairy.com get result from proxy >>
00:20 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: collector-5.testfairy.com get result from proxy >>
```

In the case of other testers we can see full logs but NOT including those above. I can see that this problematic tester uses Android 4.1.2 (API 17) on Samsung Galaxy Win (GT-I8552). Do you have any idea where we can look for problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for TestFairy :)

Let me answer this in two parts:

1. Some devices have their logging disabled completely, this means that you cannot even do `adb logcat` with the usb cable connected. Is that the case?
2. We recently push a fix (on 12 April 2015). It address a bug where some Android devices would block indefinitely when reading a certain log file. Now there's a watchdog and it will try other methods.

If you uploaded a build before the aforementioned date, can you please re-upload your APK and see if it fixes the problem?

If not, please email support directly, and we'll inspect the APK or the device you are running on.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I'll check it when I will be back at work.

Comment: @Karzmu can you please tag this with [testfairy] tag?

Comment: I will be glad to do it but that's not possible. There is no [testfairy] tag available and you need at lest 1500 reputation to create new one :(.

Comment: woohoo! I edited and added. now it's waiting for a peer review.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried following logcat filtering options?

- Filter by application tag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537430/1254211
- Filter by package name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854182/1254211

Comment: Please read the question. The problem is that we don't get logs from remote TestFairy sessions, not that we can't find application logs among other logs.

Comment: Contact TestFairy support then