# How to filter logs only with developer's logs?

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

When I am starting application I see a lot of different logs. I know that I can use tag in my class, but I don't want filter all logs by tag from one class. How can I filter all logs of application to all logs from developer? I mean logs, which was created by developer in all classes using Log class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter Android logcat by application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537419/how-to-filter-android-logcat-by-application)

Comment: This one -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/17648663/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 it's not works for me. I need only my added logs, by Log command without any another logs.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, then. You can filter by your application package name, not only a tag.

Comment: The answer of this question it is exactly what I wanted. Could you delete the duplicate label for this question?

Comment: Unless you can clarify that the linked post doesn't work  then I still believe it's a duplicate. There's no need to remove it; the accepted answer can still exist

Comment: @cricket_007 with filter by my application package name I also have a lot of unnecessary logs, with solution below I have only my personal logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the unique application prefix for all your tags:

```
public static final String APPLICATION_TAG = "MyApplicationTags; ";
```

And use it with all tags:

```
public static final String TAG = APPLICATION_TAG + "MainActivity";
```

So you can filter all logs by your application prefix.