# Package name not shown in Logcat in ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, logcat

Why does the application (package name) remains blank after upgrading ICS to Android 4.0.3, in my Eclipse logcat?

From what I understand, it is an important part of the logs and should not have been removed from Android 4.0.3.

[image]

It seems that this problem is only on [Samsung Galaxy S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S) running on Android 4.0.3, because I'm getting the package information on my Emulator (4.0, 4.0.3 and 4.1) and also on [Google Nexus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nexus) (running 4.0.5).

So is there any way we can see or get a unique identifier (apart from the package name) for an application from the Logcat?

Comment: Having the same issue but I am unable to find an answer to this question. Used to always get the package names for every application in the "Application" column. Have tried with several physical devices,  running different versions of android, none of which display the package name. I do, however, get the application tag when using an emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.
It seems that this problem is only on Samsung Galaxy running on Android 4.0.3, because I'm getting the package information on my Emulator (4.0, 4.0.3 and 4.1) and also on Google Nexus (running 4.0.5)

Answer (score 0):

Have you select your app from the device?
I didn't find that issue in my device.
Hope it helps.....

Answer (score 0):

The PID (process id) can be used for that. If you find one message of your app note the PID and filter for it. The drawback is that your app will get a new PID for each invocation.

Answer (score 0):

From my guess, you are running your app from aplications's manifirst file and not from main activity file.

1. Go and focus your main activity file(MainActivity.java), and click run.
2. Now you get a additional filter with a name of your package name in LogCat.
3. Click on that. And now you can see your application's log.

And why you not get application name on screen shot you attached is, all the process are system things.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, on `Android Studio` Beta version (0.8.*).

I rebooted the device, but the problem wasn't solved (at least yet).
Then restarted the `Android Studio` and everything was working fine. Package names were restored, so the build-in `logcat` was working like charm.

Thankfully, didn't had to mess with PIDs like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android/10239563#10239563).