# android logcat: HOWTO filter and format on command line?

Tags: android, filter, format, logcat

As far as I know, I can't filter application name from cmd, so I have to use the tags instead...

I can filter properly, but I can't get the ouput format I want...

I'm trying the following and everything works fine...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "logcat", "-d",
    BasicDefinitions.APP_TAG + ":I *:S" });
```

if I change `-d` to `-d -v long` it doesn't work anymore... the -v parameter is a valid one as stated here http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat

Comment: try [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Comment: everything is working fine already, I just can't format the output correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `String[]` type for the parameters you can not combine any of them:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "logcat", "-d", "-v", "long", BasicDefinitions.APP_TAG + ":I", "*:S" });
```

Comment: Not sure if you still care 5 years later, but I updated my answer