# Real device produce too many log

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I was developing a simple program for android. 
I tested it on a real device samsung young android 2.3.
 
My program produce some log output for debugging purpose.
 
Every thing was ok, but  my device began to produce a lot of messages in Eclipse LogCat window, even when my prog was not running. Device produces messages like this:

```
02-08 09:14:51.960: D/CallManager(1560):  handleMessage (EVENT_SERVICE_STATE_CHANGED)
02-08 09:14:54.078: E/StatusBarPolicy(1548): ecio: 22
02-08 09:14:54.078: E/StatusBarPolicy(1548): iconLevel: 4
02-08 09:14:56.640: E/StatusBarPolicy(1548): ecio: 23
02-08 09:14:56.640: E/StatusBarPolicy(1548): iconLevel: 4
02-08 09:14:59.203: E/StatusBarPolicy(1548): ecio: 24
02-08 09:14:59.203: E/StatusBarPolicy(1548): iconLevel: 4

02-08 09:16:00.007: E/ClockWidget(3324): getOrientation portrait
02-08 09:16:00.007: E/ClockWidget(3324): drawDayText
02-08 09:16:00.007: E/ClockWidget(3324): width= 50
02-08 09:16:00.007: E/ClockWidget(3324): widthText= 63.0
02-08 09:16:00.015: E/ClockWidget(3324): RIGHT
02-08 09:16:00.640: E/StatusBarPolicy(1548): ecio: 26
02-08 09:16:00.640: E/StatusBarPolicy(1548): iconLevel: 4

02-08 09:18:26.617: D/BatteryService(1495): CHARGER :: mBatteryStatus = 4
02-08 09:18:26.617: D/BatteryService(1495): updateBattery level:99 scale:100 status:4 health:2 present:false voltage: 4 temperature: 340 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17302184
02-08 09:18:26.632: D/WifiService(1495): [mPersistState] : On
02-08 09:18:26.632: I/StatusBarPolicy(1548): BAT. S:4 H:2
02-08 09:18:26.656: D/Vold(1306): VolumeManager::handleSwitchEvent -> Changed USB status SWITCH_NAME(usb_mass_storage),SWITCH_STATE(offline) 
02-08 09:18:26.656: W/Vold(1306): Ignoring unknown switch 'usb_mass_storage'
02-08 09:18:26.656: D/Vold(1306): VolumeManager::handleSwitchEvent -> Changed USB status SWITCH_NAME(usb_connected),SWITCH_STATE(0) 
02-08 09:18:26.656: W/Vold(1306): Ignoring unknown switch 'usb_connected'

02-08 09:18:27.078: I/PowerManagerService(1495): Light Animator Finished curIntValue=143
02-08 09:18:27.242: D/AndroidRuntime(13895): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-08 09:18:27.242: D/AndroidRuntime(13895): CheckJNI is OFF
02-08 09:18:27.242: I/AndroidRuntime(13895): JNI options: '-Xjniopts:warnonly'
02-08 09:18:27.242: E/AndroidRuntime(13895): feature code ==> cannot open file
02-08 09:18:27.421: D/LibQmg_native(13895): register_android_app_LibQmg
02-08 09:18:27.476: D/AndroidRuntime(13895): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
```

And so on. Device generates it constantly, i can't stop it. 
When i run my programm it becomes impossible to find usefull log messages.

How can i stop my device producing such messages?

Comment: bcz so many service run in background in real device dats y its shows too many log

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41860849/2870088

Comment: Related posts - [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6854127/465053) & [How to filter logcat in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19931987/465053)

Answer (score 3):

Just create a filter for your own application.

**STEPS:**

1. Go in the DDMS perspective.
2. In the logcat tab, click on the **green + sign** which wil bring up the following pop-up
   [image]
3. In the **by Application Name:** section, put in your root namespace. For example: *com.abc.testapp*

*Alternative method:*
If you haven't tried the earlier option, while still in the *All Message* section of logcat, find the stacktrace that is for your application -> Right Click -> *Filter similar message*. Clear out everything other than the **by Application Name** and you will get the same result.

Now you will have two entries in your logcat tab. One for all message and one for your application.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, if you have the DDMS perspective open, you can select the application from the filters. If there is none create, you can create your own filters.

Check [this](http://jtomlinson.blogspot.com/2010/04/android-ddms-and-formatting-logcat.html) out for more information.