# How do I filter logcat messages in the terminal without a tag?

Tags: android, logcat

Android Studio's logcat is unusable; it goes in and out and rarely shows messages on restart, so I've started using adb logcat on my terminal.  Reading http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html gives examples of filtering with a tag.  What if I don't know the tag, but want to show all error with an error substring I know?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio

Comment: Also note that you have access to the Android Device Monitor from Android Studio (Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor). That basically gives you a few of the Eclipse ADT perspectives, including DDMS, in a standalone GUI. Hence, you can view LogCat through there, if you prefer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always simply pipe the logcat to grep:

```
$ adb logcat | grep 'known error substring'
```

If you are on Windows, then use `find` instead:

```
C:\> adb logcat | find 'known error substring'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**pidcat**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) (by Jake Wharton).

It's a **"colored logcat script which only shows log entries for a specific application package"**, as the author says.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, you can `clic on left upper corner > Edit > Search` and then introduce the substring you know.

Most probably the terminal for Linux has the same feature, but I don't know how to access to it.