# Android Studio doesn't display logs by package name

Tags: android, logging, android-studio, android-logcat, android-log

After running a project in log is added filter such as "app: My_Package_Name"

in /.idea/workspace.xml added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="AndroidConfiguredLogFilters">
    <filters>
      <filter>
        <option name="logLevel" value="verbose" />
        <option name="logMessagePattern" value="" />
        <option name="logTagPattern" value="" />
        <option name="name" value="app: com.zastavok.net" />
        <option name="packageNamePattern" value="com.zastavok.net" />
        <option name="pid" value="" />
      </filter>
    </filters>
```

But in this filter no results:
[image]

But if I change filter to "No Filters", all results are displayed:
[image]

How to solve this problem with logs by Package_Name?

Comment: can you use filter with just this option `<option name="packageNamePattern" value="com.zastavok.net" />` ?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira no effect

Comment: hmm try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Logs wasn't display because my app doesn't display in process.

So finally I got it working, by:
Click on

[image]

Checking 'Show all processes' checkbox!

BUT as you see in the question, checkbox was on at the beginning, so there were multiple issues.

To summarize, these are other actions to be done:

- Kill all adb processes (use ps -x | grep adb and kill -9 ****)
- adb start-server in terminal
- Reconnect device
- adb device (to make sure device is connected successfully)
- Make sure Android DDMS Devices | logcat shows your app and only one device is    listed.
- Check Show all processes checkbox