# Android Studio, My APP not showing in LogCat out put

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I am running my app in debug mode. But it is not showing the Logcat.

The logcat is working and prints lots of rubbish. At the top next to the device connected  it says. No Debuggable Application. how came ?

Comment: try to restart Android studio

Comment: @Joolah did you add any external module or package into your project

Answer (score 1):

Go to your **build.gradle** and set
 *debuggable* **true**
on the build type you want.
Here's an example

```
android {

    //...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        customDebuggableBuildType {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a reference to where I got the answer from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34135791/10004454

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution by: @nick-unuchek - Than you

[Android Studio doesn't display logs by package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147936/android-studio-doesnt-display-logs-by-package-name)

Logs wasn't display because my app doesn't display in process.

So finally I got it working, by: Click on

enter image description here

Checking 'Show all processes' checkbox!

BUT as you see in the question, checkbox was on at the beginning, so there were multiple issues.

To summarize, these are other actions to be done:

Kill all adb processes (use ps -x | grep adb and kill -9 ****)
adb start-server in terminal
Reconnect device
adb device (to make sure device is connected successfully)
Make sure Android DDMS Devices | logcat shows your app and only one device is listed.
Check Show all processes checkbox