# Errors with empty new android project

Tags: android

I created a new project with android studio and I tried to debug it using my Samsung Ace 3. I get loads of errors in the logcat, but I don't know what to try. I tried changing the manifest so that the targeting SDK is 18, and the minimum is 15, and maximum is 21.

```
06-05 09:19:26.220      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:28.112    3328-4769/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telephony.CellIdentityWcdma', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.herrevad.h.f.a
06-05 09:19:28.112    3328-4769/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telephony.CellInfoWcdma', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.herrevad.h.f.a
06-05 09:19:28.142    3328-4769/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telephony.CellInfoWcdma', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.herrevad.h.k.f
06-05 09:19:29.223      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:29.914    4810-4810/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
06-05 09:19:32.226      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:35.219      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:35.419    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ On change is called.false
06-05 09:19:35.419    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ URI of the playlistcontent://media/external/audio/playlists
06-05 09:19:35.469    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ Count2mCount2
06-05 09:19:35.469    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ Neither deleted nor added. Could be rename
06-05 09:19:35.469    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ It is not renamed
06-05 09:19:35.469    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ The DB is renamed.
06-05 09:19:35.469    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ playlist path before updatePlaylistPath
06-05 09:19:35.480    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ playlist is not renamed & m3u case
06-05 09:19:37.372    1412-1412/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.
06-05 09:19:38.222      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:40.335    1412-1412/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.
06-05 09:19:40.875    3328-4994/? E/WakeLock﹕ callingPackage is not supposed to be empty for wakelock Config Service fetch!
06-05 09:19:41.226      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:41.386    1412-1412/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.
06-05 09:19:44.229      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:45.500    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ On change is called.false
06-05 09:19:45.500    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ URI of the playlistcontent://media/external/audio/playlists
06-05 09:19:45.550    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ Count2mCount2
06-05 09:19:45.550    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ Neither deleted nor added. Could be rename
06-05 09:19:45.550    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ It is not renamed
06-05 09:19:45.550    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ The DB is renamed.
06-05 09:19:45.560    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ playlist path before updatePlaylistPath
06-05 09:19:45.560    4362-4362/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr﹕ playlist is not renamed & m3u case
06-05 09:19:47.232      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:49.464    5083-5108/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.e.b
06-05 09:19:50.235      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:53.228      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:55.361    1274-1274/? E/CscFactoryReceiver﹕ onReceive android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
06-05 09:19:55.381    1274-1274/? E/CscUpdateService﹕ costomer file is exists : it has been preconfiged.
06-05 09:19:55.381    1274-1274/? E/CscUpdateService﹕ costomer file is exists : it has been preconfiged.
06-05 09:19:55.381    1274-1274/? E/CscUpdateService﹕ costomer file is exists : it has been preconfiged.
06-05 09:19:55.391    1274-5224/? E/CscParser﹕ update(): xml file exist
06-05 09:19:55.401    1274-5226/? E/CscParser﹕ update(): xml file exist
06-05 09:19:55.411    1274-5225/? E/CscParser﹕ update(): xml file exist
06-05 09:19:56.232      281-281/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
06-05 09:19:57.163    1496-1496/? E/BluetoothA2dpServiceJni﹕ Failed for on Track changed response, status: 2
06-05 09:19:57.163    1496-1496/? E/BluetoothA2dpServiceJni﹕ Failed for on play state changed response, status: 2
06-05 09:19:57.473    1496-1496/? E/BluetoothA2dpServiceJni﹕ Failed for on Track changed response, status: 2
06-05 09:19:57.513    1496-1496/? E/BluetoothA2dpServiceJni﹕ Failed for on play state changed response, status: 2
```

Comment: These errors are coming from your device in general, not necessarily your specific project. Is your phone custom rom?

Comment: Try restarting your phone. Really.

Comment: Oh really. Ok I'l try restarting my phone. Should I do a complete reboot?

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing logcat for your whole device (all other apps/services). To only see logcat for your project, set your logcat filter (drop-down list usually on the right side) to this:

> "Show only selected application"

Your logcat window should then display only the lines related to your app.

**More Info**:

If you haven't already, make sure you've followed Google's [Getting Started](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) tutorial. Specifically, see [Running Your App](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice).

Make sure your device is connected, ADB is running, and you've selected Run 'App' from the menu (app should load on your device, not the emulator).

If you've done all of this, you should see logcat in the bottom window and there should be options for filtering the output. If you don't see "Show only selected application" on the right side, your platform/version of Android Studio might be different than mine. Either way though, you can still create manual filters.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio) for more info on how to setup filters.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked the drop down menu. There is no "Show only selected application". Only option are "No Filters" and "Edit Filter Configuration".

Comment: I believe I used to have that option. Can you tell me how to get it back.