# Why logcat showing nothing about my application ? after adding filters?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I observed that when i use Logcat with Android Studio , I get messages from many other applications as well.I applied filtering option but ,now it is not showing anything related to my application.Any other solution for this problem??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter logcat in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dropdown at the top right corner in logcat window, which should be displaying ***No Filters*** by default, and choose ***Edit Filter Configuration*** and add your ***Package Name*** to show logs from that app only(Set the configuration selected).

Answer (score 0):

in the bottom of Editor, select tab Android.
At the right side you can see options to select log type to show.[image]