# Where can I print out logs to see immediately in Android Studio?

Tags: android, error-handling, logcat

I'm using Android studio and want to print out errors and warnings to somewhere like console for debugging.
How can I do this?
I know Logcat, but there is always full of logs and I cannot find mine.

Comment: Try filtering your log. See this answer [How to filter logcat in Android Studio?]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use error log to print your stacktrace. Error log has less messages and you can easily find out your message. If you are using try/catch block:

```
try
{
    //your code
}
catch(Exception e)
{    
Log.e("error tag", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
```

Comment: Where are the errors printed when using printStackTrace()?

Comment: They are printed with log tag System.err.

Answer (score 1):

Logcat is the way to go. It is possible to filter logcat based on just the output coming from your application, or just a specific tag to make it easier to see the output you want.

Take a look here for details about how to filter logcat in Android Studio:

[How to filter logcat in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio)