# Can we hide Android system level logs for my app?

Tags: android, logging

Is it possible to hide Android system level logs like these:
I am using the following command in my terminal: "adb logcat"

And the logs are like this

```
I/ActivityManager(  935): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.whatsapp/.Main bnds=[647,1532][847,1784] (has extras)} from uid 10050 on display 0

V/WindowManager(  935): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{7be16c8 token=Token{2fe83b6b ActivityRecord{3bf550ba u0 com.whatsapp/.Main t258}}} to stack=1 task=258 at 0
```

so basically can an Android app hide these logs?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio

Comment: @piotrek1543 please read the question carefully,i know how to use filters ,what i wanted to achieve was not let user of my app view these system level logs.

Comment: "so basically can any Android app hide these logs?" -- no, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare  and they all negated my question. :(

Comment: someone negate your question beacuse of low quality post and able to edit. It's not because of question, but quality of post ;-)