# Android App crashes without any logcat or any exception

Tags: android, crash, logcat

Good day.I have very weird situation.The app crashes on some point but not as it usually will crash.The app goes back to previous activity or completelly quiting the application without showing the dialog "UNFORTUNATALLY APP CLOSED" and the android studio did not giving any exception log.This behaviour i assume is a crash...This happens on couple devices which are huaweu p8 lite with lollipop version(default kitkat) and sony xperia z with lollipop version (default 4.2.2).Im unable to debug the app at all and the crash at all...On the rest devices the app wont crash or wont restart or wont quit so i have no clue whats wrong with it...Please can you help me?

build gradle file which might be the option of weird "crash"

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder/raw/master/repository'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/intercom/intercom-maven'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sparklingzoo.framkalla"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 303
        versionName "3.0.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.javatuples:javatuples:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'rapid.decoder:library:0.3.0'
    compile 'rapid.decoder:jpeg-decoder:0.3.0'
    compile 'rapid.decoder:png-decoder:0.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.1'
    compile('com.wu-man:android-oauth-client:0.0.3') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':pk-library')
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile ('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.+@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v3.3.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: I had this problem too. You could try to remove the filter from logcat, so it will show you every message, not just from your app. I was then able to see, what caused the crash. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19948588/4791726)

Comment: I really hope you don't have any filter set on logcat window. Do you?

Comment: no :( filters all off everything off i see fully the log of the system too but when i hit on that damned button the app again "crashes " and no errors...... i cant handle the errors this way...its impossible to track...

Comment: so it showed up, after removing the filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: I think there are some AndroidX refactors left in your resources (layout) XML files. Check them if any android support library references are left.

Comment: Things that help me: detach mobile from system, restart mobile, attach again, logs started showing.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

I had this situation too. Especially when it came to bugs in the framework, instead of coding bugs (Sometimes it were native crashes).

It helps to remove all filters from logcat, so that you can see all logs, not only the log of your app. In the upper right corner of your logcat, set the filters to "No Filters" and to "Verbose".

[image: Logcat filter options]

**UPDATE:**
With Android Studio 3.0 the Logcat changed a bit. The Logcat window itself has no filter options anymore. Instead, if you click on the (new) Logcat tab in the lower left corner, a new logcat window is opened, but the filter options are visible in the tab itself.

Comment: Also checking if you are finishing an activity.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and it was to do with the emulator being offline, nothing at all happens when you hit run.  I selected Wipe Data from the drop down list in the AVD manager and then it worked normally again after this.