# An activity somehow works but is not visible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I am currently working on modifying an existing app. Everything worked perfectly before and I have no idea what went wrong. Basically:

1. When you start the app there's a splash screen
2. After 2 seconds there's a login screen
3. After you log in there should be a main screen but apparently the app turns off

What is happening:

1. Splash.java - after 2 seconds it starts MainActivity

   ```
   public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

   private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Log.e("Splash", "startActivity");
            Splash.this.finish();
            Log.e("Splash", "finish");
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
   }
   }
   ```
2. MainActivity.java - apparently it works correctly - I put log messages in here and Logcat tells me that methods are running and setContentView is working as well.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "onCreate");

    startTimerService();

    //LanguageHelper.onAttach(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setVisible(true);

    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "setContentView");

    initUI();
    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "initUI");

    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.bringToFront();
    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "toolbar");

    if(firstRun)
    {
        //YOUR FIRST RUN CODE HERE
        //int i  = RfidReaderSingleton.getInstance(this).RestoreFactory();

        //////////////////////////////////
        //checkCredentials();
        /////////////////////////////////

        checkForUpdates();
        checkBluetooth();
        //tcp_buttonToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FIRST RUN: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    firstRun = false;

    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "firstRun" + firstRun);

    showPhoneStatePermission();
    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "showPhoneStatePermission");

   }
   ```

CheckCredentials is responsible for opening logging screen and this part works as well.

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    sendMessage(MSG_HIDE_WAIT, null);

    //ToDo
    checkCredentials();

    //GRID
    InitTest(this);
    Log.e("MainActivity", "InitTest");
    //GRID
}

private void checkCredentials(){
    UserModel userModel = DBUserAdapter.getInstance(this).userOperation.getUserModel();
    if(userModel.isRemembered()){
        if(!userModel.isLicenseActivated()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getText(R.string.logging_result_401) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("We'startLoginActivity", "1");
            startLoginActivity();
        }
        if(userModel.getToken().equals("")){
            Log.e("We'startLoginActivity", "2");
            startLoginActivity();

        }
    }
    else{
        if(!userModel.isUserStillLogin()){
            DBUserAdapter.getInstance(this).userOperation.cleanUserModel();
            Log.e("We'startLoginActivity", "3");
            startLoginActivity();
        }
    }
    DBUserAdapter.getInstance(this).userOperation.updateLastLogin();
    HttpUtils.SetToken(userModel.getToken());
}

 private void startLoginActivity(){
    mStartForResult.launch(new Intent(this, PlatformLoginActivity.class));
}
```

3. After a correct log in the PlatformLoginActivity is finished and this is when the problem happens. The app just kind of turns off but theres no error in Logcat - no message. The MainActivity that was created after a SplashScreen successfully (because MainActivity is responsible for opening PlatformLoginActivity ans this happened correctly). When PlatformLoginActivity finishes the MainActivity is not visible, app turns off but the toastmessage that belongs to MainActivity is visible in the screen.

I have never before seen such a behavior and I have no idea what may be the problem - I tried to log what is happening in the app but apparently it works.

Any help would be highly appreciated as I have no idea what to do.

The message from logcat:

```
2020-12-16 10:11:17.569 3984-3984/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-12-16 10:11:17.570 3984-3984/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-12-16 10:11:17.604 3984-3984/? E/heldrfidscanne: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-12-16 10:11:21.250 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/Splash: startActivity
2020-12-16 10:11:21.253 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/Splash: finish
2020-12-16 10:11:21.293 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: onCreate
2020-12-16 10:11:21.478 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: setContentView
2020-12-16 10:11:21.480 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: buttonsAction
2020-12-16 10:11:21.531 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: gridView
2020-12-16 10:11:21.531 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: initUI
2020-12-16 10:11:21.532 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: toolbar
2020-12-16 10:11:21.545 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: bluetoothconn: null
2020-12-16 10:11:21.545 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: firstRunfalse
2020-12-16 10:11:21.545 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/showPhoneStatePermiss: OK
2020-12-16 10:11:21.546 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/permissionCheck: NOT GRANTED
2020-12-16 10:11:21.569 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/requestPermission: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
2020-12-16 10:11:21.593 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: showPhoneStatePermission
2020-12-16 10:11:21.663 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We'startLoginActivity: 3
2020-12-16 10:11:21.685 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: InitTest
2020-12-16 10:11:21.947 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/PlatformLoginActivity: requestPermissions
2020-12-16 10:11:33.911 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/Sign in button clicked: success
2020-12-16 10:11:34.052 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySUQiOiIwN2I5MmE1My01NDEwLTRhMDYtOGM3MC0xY2UwYzllMTdkMjQiLCJyb2xlIjoiUmVndWxhciIsIm5iZiI6MTYwODEwOTg5NSwiZXhwIjoxNjE1ODg1ODk1LCJpYXQiOjE2MDgxMDk4OTV9.uxLK0qnEH3e9SjXYroBtWVKC56cHl4CmVnUlzFVgVtE
2020-12-16 10:11:34.052 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/token is NOT null: OK
2020-12-16 10:11:34.055 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/userName: issdemo
2020-12-16 10:11:34.055 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/userRole: Regular
2020-12-16 10:11:34.055 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/accountType: 0
2020-12-16 10:11:34.085 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We're in onSignIn: OK
2020-12-16 10:11:34.136 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We're in onSignIn: if condition
2020-12-16 10:11:34.136 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We're in onSignIn: MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_ANNOTATION
2020-12-16 10:11:34.141 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We're in onSignIn: finish()
```

Logcat with NO filter on:

```
2020-12-16 10:11:19.341 3739-3956/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2020-12-16 10:11:19.351 4222-4492/? E/NetdEventListenerService: handleMessage: { when=-2ms what=10001 obj=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsResultParams@6e0c47d target=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsEventHandler }
2020-12-16 10:11:19.499 4222-4431/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{b3aa12c u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1199 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1180 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.notifyAppStopped:1235 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStoppedLocked:2597 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.activityStopped:2380 android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub.onTransact:2180 android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal:1056 
2020-12-16 10:11:19.530 4222-4274/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{bd74f7a u0 Splash Screen pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1199 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1180 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5030 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:287 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:5471 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$yVRF8YoeNdTa8GR1wDStVsHu8xM.run:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:100 
2020-12-16 10:11:19.741 4222-4628/? E/MdnieScenarioControlService: Exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/mdnie/mdnie/scenario: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) , in : null , value : null , length : 0
2020-12-16 10:11:21.250 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/Splash: startActivity
2020-12-16 10:11:21.253 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/Splash: finish
2020-12-16 10:11:21.293 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: onCreate
2020-12-16 10:11:21.478 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: setContentView
2020-12-16 10:11:21.480 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: buttonsAction
2020-12-16 10:11:21.531 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: gridView
2020-12-16 10:11:21.531 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: initUI
2020-12-16 10:11:21.532 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: toolbar
2020-12-16 10:11:21.545 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: bluetoothconn: null
2020-12-16 10:11:21.545 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: firstRunfalse
2020-12-16 10:11:21.545 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/showPhoneStatePermiss: OK
2020-12-16 10:11:21.546 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/permissionCheck: NOT GRANTED
2020-12-16 10:11:21.548 3739-3956/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2020-12-16 10:11:21.551 4222-4492/? E/NetdEventListenerService: handleMessage: { when=0 what=10001 obj=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsResultParams@1f35706 target=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsEventHandler }
2020-12-16 10:11:21.569 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/requestPermission: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
2020-12-16 10:11:21.593 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: main activity: showPhoneStatePermission
2020-12-16 10:11:21.663 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We'startLoginActivity: 3
2020-12-16 10:11:21.685 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/MainActivity: InitTest
2020-12-16 10:11:21.947 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/PlatformLoginActivity: requestPermissions
2020-12-16 10:11:22.534 4222-4628/? E/MdnieScenarioControlService: Exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/mdnie/mdnie/scenario: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) , in : null , value : null , length : 0
2020-12-16 10:11:22.850 3785-6164/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner.activity.Splash$_3984#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:23.602 3785-4217/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Toast$_3984#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:24.675 3739-3956/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2020-12-16 10:11:24.678 4222-4492/? E/NetdEventListenerService: handleMessage: { when=0 what=10001 obj=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsResultParams@81a53a4 target=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsEventHandler }
2020-12-16 10:11:24.717 3785-3842/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.google.android.permissioncontroller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity$_2617#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:24.942 4222-4628/? E/MdnieScenarioControlService: Exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/mdnie/mdnie/scenario: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) , in : null , value : null , length : 0
2020-12-16 10:11:25.030 4222-4274/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{8108b8f u0 com.google.android.permissioncontroller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1199 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1180 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5030 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:287 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:5471 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$yVRF8YoeNdTa8GR1wDStVsHu8xM.run:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:100 
2020-12-16 10:11:25.971 4523-4523/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-12-16 10:11:25.973 4523-4523/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-12-16 10:11:25.985 4523-4523/? E/ungpassautofil: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-12-16 10:11:25.986 6667-6667/? E/SKBDC: SSTAC init()::current version is 2.11.02.U2.T1
2020-12-16 10:11:25.986 6667-6667/? E/SKBDC: SSTAC [init] mLanguageCode : 589838, tempLanguageCode : 589838, getPreloadLmLoadSuccessState() : 1
2020-12-16 10:11:26.037 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:26.114 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:26.165 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:26.986 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:27.203 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:27.379 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:27.983 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:28.302 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:28.479 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:29.094 3785-3842/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [PopupWindow:badd8b9$_6667#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:29.138 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:29.195 6667-6667/? E/SKBD: cal Dismiss keyPreviewView is null
2020-12-16 10:11:29.316 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:29.514 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:29.715 3785-3841/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [PopupWindow:badd8b9$_6667#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:29.767 6667-6667/? E/oid.inputmetho: Resource 01120067 is a complex map type.
2020-12-16 10:11:29.767 6667-6667/? E/SKBD: caf getSystemDimesionPixelSize: NotFoundException, name =  keyboardViewStyle
2020-12-16 10:11:29.783 6667-6667/? E/SKBDC: SSTAC init()::current version is 2.11.02.U2.T1
2020-12-16 10:11:29.783 6667-6667/? E/SKBDC: SSTAC [init] mLanguageCode : 589838, tempLanguageCode : 589838, getPreloadLmLoadSuccessState() : 1
2020-12-16 10:11:29.795 6667-6667/? E/SKBD: ctm get previous
2020-12-16 10:11:29.837 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:30.294 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:30.325 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:30.443 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:30.926 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:31.240 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:31.676 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:31.907 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:32.124 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:32.584 6667-6667/? E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-12-16 10:11:33.253 3785-5552/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [PopupWindow:6ef797a$_6667#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:33.311 3785-3842/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [InputMethod$_6667#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:33.911 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/Sign in button clicked: success
2020-12-16 10:11:33.953 3739-3956/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2020-12-16 10:11:33.956 4222-4492/? E/NetdEventListenerService: handleMessage: { when=0 what=10001 obj=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsResultParams@5cdb978 target=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsEventHandler }
2020-12-16 10:11:34.052 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySUQiOiIwN2I5MmE1My01NDEwLTRhMDYtOGM3MC0xY2UwYzllMTdkMjQiLCJyb2xlIjoiUmVndWxhciIsIm5iZiI6MTYwODEwOTg5NSwiZXhwIjoxNjE1ODg1ODk1LCJpYXQiOjE2MDgxMDk4OTV9.uxLK0qnEH3e9SjXYroBtWVKC56cHl4CmVnUlzFVgVtE
2020-12-16 10:11:34.052 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/token is NOT null: OK
2020-12-16 10:11:34.055 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/userName: issdemo
2020-12-16 10:11:34.055 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/userRole: Regular
2020-12-16 10:11:34.055 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/accountType: 0
2020-12-16 10:11:34.085 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We're in onSignIn: OK
2020-12-16 10:11:34.136 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We're in onSignIn: if condition
2020-12-16 10:11:34.136 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We're in onSignIn: MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_ANNOTATION
2020-12-16 10:11:34.141 3984-3984/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner E/We're in onSignIn: finish()
2020-12-16 10:11:34.193 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:11:34.241 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:11:34.286 6500-6738/? E/PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[28588910426393442] not persisted.
2020-12-16 10:11:34.463 3785-3785/? E/Layer: [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{fc38cea token=Token{8130cd5 ActivityRecord{4b03d8c u0 pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner/.activity.PlatformLoginActivity t151}}})/@0xb9522e4 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found, barrierLayer : [com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity$_5070#0]
2020-12-16 10:11:34.463 3785-3785/? E/Layer: [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{fc38cea token=Token{8130cd5 ActivityRecord{4b03d8c u0 pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner/.activity.PlatformLoginActivity t151}}})/@0xb9522e4 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found, barrierLayer : [com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity$_5070#0]
2020-12-16 10:11:34.463 3785-3785/? E/Layer: [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{d6f3421 token=Token{80a8288 ActivityRecord{2b7fe2b u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/.activities.LauncherActivity t118}}})/@0x8bb7866 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found, barrierLayer : [com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity$_5070#0]
2020-12-16 10:11:34.463 3785-3785/? E/Layer: [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{d6f3421 token=Token{80a8288 ActivityRecord{2b7fe2b u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/.activities.LauncherActivity t118}}})/@0x8bb7866 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found, barrierLayer : [com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity$_5070#0]
2020-12-16 10:11:34.463 3785-3785/? E/Layer: [Surface(name=49d29cb com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper)/@0x708e9c5 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found, barrierLayer : [com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity$_5070#0]
2020-12-16 10:11:34.463 3785-3785/? E/Layer: [Surface(name=49d29cb com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper)/@0x708e9c5 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found, barrierLayer : [com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity$_5070#0]
2020-12-16 10:11:34.470 3785-4217/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner/pl.issrfid.isshandheldrfidscanner.activity.PlatformLoginActivity$_3984#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:34.556 4222-4628/? E/MdnieScenarioControlService: Exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/mdnie/mdnie/scenario: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) , in : null , value : null , length : 0
2020-12-16 10:11:34.692 4222-4628/? E/MdnieScenarioControlService: Exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/mdnie/mdnie/scenario: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) , in : null , value : null , length : 0
2020-12-16 10:11:34.948 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 190 [2020-12-16 10:11:34.948] FD count : 599, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:11:36.100 3785-5552/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Toast$_3984#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-12-16 10:11:44.530 3739-3956/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2020-12-16 10:11:44.589 4222-4492/? E/NetdEventListenerService: handleMessage: { when=-1ms what=10001 obj=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsResultParams@7bf6a0a target=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsEventHandler }
2020-12-16 10:11:48.146 4733-4656/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-12-16 10:11:54.269 5728-4657/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-12-16 10:12:04.954 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 191 [2020-12-16 10:12:04.954] FD count : 598, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:12:06.381 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:12:06.432 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:12:34.967 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 192 [2020-12-16 10:12:34.966] FD count : 532, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:13:00.010 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:13:00.058 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:13:04.980 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 193 [2020-12-16 10:13:04.980] FD count : 532, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:13:34.993 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 194 [2020-12-16 10:13:34.992] FD count : 532, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:14:00.012 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:14:00.050 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:14:05.005 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 195 [2020-12-16 10:14:05.005] FD count : 532, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:14:35.018 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 196 [2020-12-16 10:14:35.018] FD count : 532, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:15:00.010 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:15:00.048 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:15:05.030 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 197 [2020-12-16 10:15:05.030] FD count : 532, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:15:35.043 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 198 [2020-12-16 10:15:35.042] FD count : 532, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:16:00.018 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:16:00.052 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:16:05.056 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 199 [2020-12-16 10:16:05.055] FD count : 532, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:16:06.693 3739-3956/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2020-12-16 10:16:06.699 4222-4492/? E/NetdEventListenerService: handleMessage: { when=-1ms what=10001 obj=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsResultParams@eddcc78 target=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsEventHandler }
2020-12-16 10:16:35.068 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 200 [2020-12-16 10:16:35.068] FD count : 526, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:16:48.245 4733-4727/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-12-16 10:16:54.368 5728-4728/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-12-16 10:16:55.023 4901-5501/? E/EPDG -- SIM0 [RILRECEIVER]: Incorrect EpdgIilIpcMessage IPC Message -- not initialized
2020-12-16 10:16:55.030 4554-5292/? E/ImsAdaptorImpl: setSSACInfo : ImsAdaptorImpl.
2020-12-16 10:16:55.044 4901-5501/? E/EPDG -- SIM0 [RILRECEIVER]: Incorrect EpdgIilIpcMessage IPC Message -- not initialized
2020-12-16 10:16:55.045 4554-5292/? E/ImsAdaptorImpl: setSSACInfo : ImsAdaptorImpl.
2020-12-16 10:16:55.053 4901-5501/? E/EPDG -- SIM0 [RILRECEIVER]: RX [NET_REGIST] -- RESPONSE -- not initialized
2020-12-16 10:16:55.194 4729-4729/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-12-16 10:16:55.197 4729-4729/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-12-16 10:16:55.219 4729-4729/? E/droid.messagin: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-12-16 10:16:55.221 4738-4738/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-12-16 10:16:55.223 4738-4738/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-12-16 10:16:55.245 4738-4738/? E/app.telephonyu: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-12-16 10:16:55.518 4738-4816/? E/ServiceBindHelper: time out 68, com.samsung.telephony.phone.service.internalservice.ISamsungInternalService$Stub$Proxy@ebbb05c
2020-12-16 10:16:55.658 4729-4805/? E/ORC/CustomerFeatureCommon: initDocument
2020-12-16 10:16:55.737 4873-5576/? E/CapabilityDiscModule<0>: checkModuleReady: module is disabled
2020-12-16 10:16:55.750 4729-4850/? E/CS/OwnCapabilityManager<0>: queryOwnCapability, cursor null
2020-12-16 10:16:55.817 4729-4822/? E/CS/CommonDbUtils: transactionMakeFail : Not exist transaction msg
2020-12-16 10:16:55.833 4873-5575/? E/CapabilityDiscModule<0>: checkModuleReady: module is disabled
2020-12-16 10:16:55.859 4729-4850/? E/CS/OwnCapabilityManager<0>: queryOwnCapability, cursor null
2020-12-16 10:16:55.890 4873-5575/? E/CapabilityDiscModule<0>: checkModuleReady: module is disabled
2020-12-16 10:16:55.893 4729-4870/? E/CS/OwnCapabilityManager<0>: queryOwnCapability, cursor null
2020-12-16 10:17:05.081 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 201 [2020-12-16 10:17:05.080] FD count : 526, wdog_way : softdog
2020-12-16 10:17:05.531 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:17:05.584 5070-5070/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-12-16 10:17:35.093 4222-4276/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 202 [2020-12-16 10:17:35.093] FD count : 526, wdog_way : softdog
```

Comment: do you have any messages from log cat?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364373/android-app-crashes-without-any-logcat-or-any-exception see this link if log errors ot showing

Comment: @georkost I have added the message that I got in the logcat

Comment: Can you post your `MainActivity` fully?

Comment: I have posted it below @akhilnair

Comment: `We're in onSignIn: finish()` when this is calling?

Answer (score 0):

I know that I should post this in my post and not in here but unfortunately the question can have only 30000 characters and the code I' about to post exceeds that limitation

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends BluetoothActivityCompat implements ICallback {

private static MainActivity mInstance;
private static boolean firstRun = true;
public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private final int MSG_ENTER_INFO = MSG_USER_BEG + 3;
private final int MSG_ENTER_USER = MSG_USER_BEG + 4;
private final int MSG_ENTER_SCANNER = MSG_USER_BEG + 5;
private final int MSG_ENTER_INVENTORY = MSG_USER_BEG + 6;
private final int MSG_ENTER_DATABASE = MSG_USER_BEG + 7;
private final int MSG_ENTER_REPORT = MSG_USER_BEG + 8;
private final int MSG_CONNECTION_ERROR = MSG_USER_BEG + 9;
private final int MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_ANNOTATION = 301;

private ConnectBluetoothDeviceDialog connectBluetoothDeviceDialog;

//GRID
private RecyclerView locations_recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter locations_mAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private ArrayList<LocationModel> locationsList = new ArrayList<LocationModel>();
//GRID

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "onCreate");

    startTimerService();

    LanguageHelper.onAttach(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setVisible(true);

    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "setContentView");

    initUI();
    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "initUI");

    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.bringToFront();
    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "toolbar");

    if(firstRun)
    {
        //YOUR FIRST RUN CODE HERE
        //int i  = RfidReaderSingleton.getInstance(this).RestoreFactory();

        //////////////////////////////////
        //checkCredentials();
        /////////////////////////////////

        checkForUpdates();
        checkBluetooth();
        //tcp_buttonToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FIRST RUN: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    firstRun = false;

    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "firstRun" + firstRun);

    showPhoneStatePermission();
    Log.e(TAG, "main activity: " + "showPhoneStatePermission");

}

private void checkBluetooth(){
    try{
        String bluetoothConn = DBUserAdapter.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .userOperation
                .getUserModel()
                .getBluetoothLastConnectedDeviceName();
        Log.e(TAG, "bluetoothconn: " + bluetoothConn);
        if(bluetoothConn!=null && !bluetoothConn.isEmpty()){
            PublicData.bt4Param = bluetoothConn;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
}

private void startTimerService(){
    TimeCounterService mSensorService = new TimeCounterService(getApplicationContext());
    Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mSensorService.getClass());
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(mSensorService.getClass())) {
        startService(mServiceIntent);
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", true+"");
            return true;
        }
    }
    Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", false+"");
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    sendMessage(MSG_HIDE_WAIT, null);
    //uhfBaseActivityBluetooth.UHF_Dispose();
}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
    //sendMessage(MSG_HIDE_WAIT, null);
    //uhfBaseActivityBluetooth.UHF_Dispose();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    sendMessage(MSG_HIDE_WAIT, null);

    //ToDo
    checkCredentials();

    //GRID
    InitTest(this);
    Log.e("MainActivity", "InitTest");
    //GRID
}

private void checkCredentials(){
    UserModel userModel = DBUserAdapter.getInstance(this).userOperation.getUserModel();
    if(userModel.isRemembered()){
        if(!userModel.isLicenseActivated()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getText(R.string.logging_result_401) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("We'startLoginActivity", "1");
            startLoginActivity();
        }
        if(userModel.getToken().equals("")){
            Log.e("We'startLoginActivity", "2");
            startLoginActivity();

        }
    }
    else{
        if(!userModel.isUserStillLogin()){
            DBUserAdapter.getInstance(this).userOperation.cleanUserModel();
            Log.e("We'startLoginActivity", "3");
            startLoginActivity();
        }
    }
    DBUserAdapter.getInstance(this).userOperation.updateLastLogin();
    HttpUtils.SetToken(userModel.getToken());
}

private void checkForUpdates(){
    try{
        AppUpdater appUpdater = new AppUpdater(this)
                .setDisplay(Display.DIALOG)
                .setUpdateFrom(UpdateFrom.JSON)
                .setUpdateJSON(getString(R.string.update_info_address))
                .setTitleOnUpdateAvailable(R.string.updateTitle)
                .setButtonUpdate(R.string.updateButtonOk)
                .setButtonDismiss(R.string.updateButtonCancel)
                .setContentOnUpdateAvailable(R.string.updateInformation)
                .setButtonDoNotShowAgain(null);
        appUpdater.start();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
        Log.e("onKeyDown", "MainActivity");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void initUI(){
    buttonsAction();
    Log.e("MainActivity", "buttonsAction");

    //GRID
    locations_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.foundDevices_recyclerView);
    locations_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

    // use a linear layout manager
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    locations_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    locationsList = DBAdapter.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getLocationList();
    locations_mAdapter = new LocationAdapter(locationsList, MainActivity.this);

    locations_recyclerView.setAdapter(locations_mAdapter);
    Log.e("MainActivity", "gridView");

//        locations_recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
//            @Override
//            public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
//                int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
//                int spanCount = 3;
//                int spacing = 10;//spacing between views in grid
//
//                if (position >= 0) {
//                    int column = position % spanCount; // item column
//
//                    outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
//                    outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
//
//                    if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
//                        outRect.top = spacing;
//                    }
//                    outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
//                } else {
//                    outRect.left = 0;
//                    outRect.right = 0;
//                    outRect.top = 0;
//                    outRect.bottom = 0;
//                }
//            }
//        });

    //DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(locations_recyclerView.getContext(),
    //        linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
    //locations_recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    //GRID
}

public void refreshListView(){
    locationsList.clear();
    locationsList = DBAdapter.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getLocationList();
    locations_mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    showToast(getString(R.string.synchronization_completed));
}

void showToast(String message){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM , 0,50);

    toast.show();
}

@Override
protected void msgProcess(Message msg) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_ENTER_INFO:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserDetailActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        case MSG_ENTER_USER:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        case MSG_ENTER_DATABASE:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DatabaseActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        case MSG_ENTER_INVENTORY:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationListViewActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        case MSG_ENTER_SCANNER:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TagReadingActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        case MSG_ENTER_REPORT:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        case MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_ANNOTATION:
            Log.e("In msgProcess MainA", "case MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_ANNOTATION");
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    super.msgProcess(msg);
}

private void buttonsAction() {
    Button info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info_button);
    Button inw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inw_button);
    Button database = (Button) findViewById(R.id.database_button);
    Button scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    Button report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.report_button);
    ImageButton settings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
    ImageButton bluetooth = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_button);

    // MY NEW BUTTONS
    ImageButton bluetoothToolbar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bluetooth_button);
    ImageButton synchronizationToolbar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_synchronization_button);
    ImageButton userToolbar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_user_button);
    ImageButton infoToolbar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_info_button);

    infoToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isFastClick()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    sendMessage(MSG_SHOW_WAIT, getString(R.string.str_loading));
                    sendMessage(MSG_ENTER_USER, null);
                };
            }.start();
        }
    });

    database.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isFastClick()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    sendMessage(MSG_SHOW_WAIT, getString(R.string.str_loading));
                    sendMessage(MSG_ENTER_DATABASE, null);
                };
            }.start();
        }
    });

    inw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isFastClick()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    sendMessage(MSG_SHOW_WAIT, getString(R.string.str_loading));
                    sendMessage(MSG_ENTER_INVENTORY, null);
                };
            }.start();
        }
    });

    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isFastClick()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    sendMessage(MSG_SHOW_WAIT, getString(R.string.str_loading));
                    sendMessage(MSG_ENTER_SCANNER, null);
                };
            }.start();
        }
    });

    report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isFastClick()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    sendMessage(MSG_SHOW_WAIT, getString(R.string.str_loading));
                    sendMessage(MSG_ENTER_REPORT, null);
                };
            }.start();
        }
    });

//        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                new Thread() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void run() {
//                        if (isFastClick()) {
//                            return;
//                        }
//                        sendMessage(MSG_SHOW_WAIT, getString(R.string.str_loading));
//                        sendMessage(MSG_ENTER_INFO, null);
//                    };
//                }.start();
//
//            }
//        });




    ICallback callback = this;

    bluetoothToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fm;
            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            ConnectBluetoothDeviceDialog connectBluetoothDeviceDialog =
                    ConnectBluetoothDeviceDialog.newInstance(callback);
            connectBluetoothDeviceDialog.showDialog(fm);

        }
    });

    synchronizationToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fm;
            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            SynchronizationMainDialog synchronizationMainDialog =
                    SynchronizationMainDialog.newInstance(callback);
            synchronizationMainDialog.showDialog(fm);

        }
    });


    userToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("userToolbar button", "pressed");


            FragmentManager fm;
            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            UserDialog userDialog =
                    UserDialog.newInstance(callback);
            userDialog.showDialog(fm);

        }
    });


}

private void startLoginActivity(){
    mStartForResult.launch(new Intent(this, PlatformLoginActivity.class));
}

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_ANNOTATION) {
                    FragmentManager fm;
                    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    SynchronizationAnnotationDialog synchronizationAnnotationDialog =
                            SynchronizationAnnotationDialog.newInstance();
                    synchronizationAnnotationDialog.showDialog(fm);

                    Log.e("ActivityResultLauncher", "MSG_SYNCHRONIZE_ANNOTATION");
                    // Handle the Intent
                }
            }
});

// Checking if user has changed language using the 'InfoActivity'. If yes -cann we need to
// restart the activity to update the language.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e(TAG, "requestCode: " + requestCode);
    if(requestCode==0)
    {
        try {
            if(data.getBooleanExtra("languageChanged", false)){
                restartActivity();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
        }
    }
    if(resultCode == MSG_CONNECTION_ERROR){
        FragmentManager fm;
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        BluetoothConnectionErrorDialog bluetoothConnectionErrorDialog =
                BluetoothConnectionErrorDialog.newInstance();
        bluetoothConnectionErrorDialog.showDialog(fm);
    }
}

private void restartActivity() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}


//We are calling this method to check the permission status
private boolean isReadStorageAllowed() {
    //Getting the permission status
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    //If permission is granted returning true
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return true;

    //If permission is not granted returning false
    return false;
}

private final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;

private void showPhoneStatePermission() {

    Log.e("showPhoneStatePermiss", "OK");

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e("permissionCheck", "NOT GRANTED");

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Log.e("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "the app has requested the permission previously and the user denied the requst");

            showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);

        } else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
            Log.e("requestPermission", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
        }
    } else {
       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission (already) Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
    } else {
       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission (already) Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode,
        String permissions[],
        int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}

private void showExplanation(String title,
                             String message,
                             final String permission,
                             final int permissionRequestCode) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    requestPermission(permission, permissionRequestCode);
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}

private void requestPermission(String permissionName, int permissionRequestCode) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{permissionName}, permissionRequestCode);
}

@Override
public void showLoading() {
    sendMessage(MSG_SHOW_WAIT, getString(R.string.str_loading));
}

@Override
public void hideLoading() {
    sendMessage(MSG_HIDE_WAIT, null);
}
```

}