# What is this in LogCat ? InputTransport

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat, rx-java

In my logcat in Android Studio is going crazy full of these log below.
Does anyone know is that and how to stop ?
Thanks

```
02-25 08:28:41.090 13291-13291/com.myapp D/InputTransport: channel '18179b0f com.myapp/com.myapp.views.ui.screen.BaseActivity (client)' consumer ~ consume: consumeBatches=true, frameTime=19700766116926
```

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem?

Comment: no problem. these message all showing up non stop

Answer (score 0):

> The Android logging system provides a mechanism for collecting and
>   viewing system debug output.

```
Activity (client)' consumer ~ consume: consumeBatches=true, frameTime=19700766116926
```

Logcat dumps a log of system messages, which include things such as stack traces when the emulator throws an error and messages that you have written from your application by using the `Log class`.

When Android is running, it's generating **all kinds of system messages**.Don't worry about it .Its not **harmful** .

Comment: is there a away to disable it. This only happen in one app and working on which I am using RX. others project these message dont show up

Comment: @Joolah http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio

Comment: In your Logcat configuration choose `No filters` option.

Comment: @Stanojkovic Indeed indeed .