# Android Register form not working but data goes into database

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement an android register form which is not working as when users try to register the application just crashes and closes, however, users information does get inserted into the database.

My question is that why does it close down as the data does get inserted into the database successfully. Please advise and help.

Log cat error Message

```
 {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"fname":"crisnfg","lname":"nawadv","email":"christina@gmail.com","uname":"crisitina","uid":"56e99196d80403.95127534","created_at":"2016-03-16 17:02:14"}}
03-16 17:01:48.945 8482-11204/com.bradvisor.bradvisor E/Buffer Error: Error converting result org.json.JSONException: Value 2016-03-16 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-16 17:01:48.948 8482-8482/com.empier E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.empier, PID: 8482
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.empier.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:209)
                                                                           at com.empier.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:169)


03-16 19:34:03.519 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:34:10.110 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:34:10.198 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:35:42.417 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:35:43.093 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:37:07.778 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:38:22.195 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:40:23.161 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:42:56.833 24951-24951/com.empier D/debug_tag: true
03-16 19:58:16.518 29411-29411/? D/debug_tag: true
```

Register.Java Code

```
public class Register extends Activity {


    /**
     *  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    /**
     * Defining layout items.
     **/

    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    ImageButton btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        /**
         * Defining all layout items
         **/
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Registerbtn);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        /**
         * Register Button click event.
         * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
         * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
         **/

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                        NetAsync(view);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }


    private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) { Log.d("debug_tag", json == null ? "true" : "false");
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user"); Log.d("debug_tag", "User json :: " + json_user==null ? "true": "false");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                         **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);


                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }


                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occurred in registration");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }}
```

Userfunction.java code

```
 /**
     * Function to  Register
     **/
    public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        return json;

    }
```

Registered.java file

```
public class Registered extends Activity {



    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registered);


        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        user = db.getUserDetails();

        /**
         * Displays the registration details in Text view
         **/

        final TextView fname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        final TextView lname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lname);
        final TextView uname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uname);
        final TextView email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        final TextView created_at = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.regat);
        fname.setText(user.get("fname"));
        lname.setText(user.get("lname"));
        uname.setText(user.get("uname"));
        email.setText(user.get("email"));
        created_at.setText(user.get("created_at"));


        ImageButton loginbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.loginscreenbtn);
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

    }}
```

Register.XML File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context="bradvisor.bradvisor.com.bradvisor.LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:src="@drawable/logofinal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Registerbtn"
        android:src="@drawable/registerbtn"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pword"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:textColor="#ff3b5998"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Last Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#3b5998" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/uname"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#3b5998"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/uname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="#3b5998" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/pword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="#3b5998" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:textColor="#3b5998"
        android:id="@+id/register_error"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Registerbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

registered.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context="bradvisor.bradvisor.com.bradvisor.LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:src="@drawable/logofinal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Registerbtn"
        android:src="@drawable/registerbtn"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pword"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:textColor="#ff3b5998"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Last Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#3b5998" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/uname"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#3b5998"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/uname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="#3b5998" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/pword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="#3b5998" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:textColor="#3b5998"
        android:id="@+id/register_error"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Registerbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I debug the application I do not get anything as everything works fine. please help and advise?.

Answer (score 0):

The crash logs show that there is NullPointerException in `onPostExecute()` method. So either your `json` object which you are getting in `onPostExecute()` as a parameter is `null` or `json_user` in -

```
JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
```

is `null`. you can add logs for these 2 objects and check for null to find out which of them are causing the issue.

From the logs , it is clear that you are getting `json` object `null` sometimes in  `protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)` 
And that's why when you call `json.getString()`, you get `NullPointerException`.
To avoid the crash, 
in your `onPostExecute()` check for null and show some error message

```
if(json == null){
//Show error message toast or something
}
```

Comment: Add at the beginning of onPostExecute()  -
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) { Log.d("debug_tag", json==null ? "true": "false");  and after  this statement JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user"); add  Log.d("debug_tag", "User json :: " + json_user==null ? "true": "false");

Comment: I have this, however, I cannot see anything in the logcat as the application just closes down.

Comment: You have to filter the logcat by tag ""debug_tag"" . Then you'll see the logs.

Comment: k, I will do this now.

Comment: how shall I filter the logcat by tag""debug_tag"".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio

Comment: When checking the filters. I still cannot find anything as its now blank with ""debug_tag"". I cannot see anything as its blank now.

Comment: I don't know how are you doing it because you would at least see true or false values in your logcat if you set the filter to - debug_tag .

Comment: I will check it again.

Comment: 03-16 19:34:03.519 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:34:10.110 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:34:10.198 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:35:42.417 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:35:43.093 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:37:07.778 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:38:22.195 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false

Comment: 03-16 19:40:23.161 19048-19048/com.empier D/debug_tag: false
03-16 19:42:56.833 24951-24951/empier D/debug_tag: true
03-16 19:58:16.518 29411-29411/? D/debug_tag: true

Comment: I have added the code. However I dont understand what it all means.

Comment: I mean paste  the updated  code  after adding the Log.d() statements as I told you before.

Comment: @Maddie_J Looking at the last line of your Log, one of you JSON objects doesn't have a `"user"` key. I suggest you inspect your database to figure out why

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_id` varchar(23) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `encrypted_password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
)

Comment: I have pasted my database code which looks fine. could you please advise?.

Comment: any further advice or help please.