# Android email validation with regular expression not working

Tags: java, android

I have a regular expression to validate an email and when I run it, it constantly tells me that its an invalid email address but the email is correct

```
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);   

final String Email = email.getText().toString();

if (!Email.matches("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"))
     {
         email.requestFocus();
         email.setError("INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS");
     }
```

Does anyone know it would give me the error even though it is correct?

Comment: [Seems to work](http://ideone.com/rppPjU)

Comment: But when I run it on my android it just prints the error Invalid email address

Comment: Do you have a space at the end? That would return false. What is the content of `Email`?

Comment: How do you get `Email`? Please post that snippet too. And log the value of `Email`. Likely the error is there.

Comment: Email is just converting it to a string so that .matches can work I have edited the code

Comment: I would try `email.getText().toString().trim()` to see if there's any whitespace you're not accounting for, but I would still like to see a log statement with the contents of the Email String to see what you're testing against.

Comment: .trim() didn't work but I can't seem to find the log statement regarding Email String

Comment: What is that "else"? It seems that you set email var on one "if" branch and check its value in another...

Comment: It was an else if because I had an if above it that checks that email wasn't empty

Answer (score 0):

try this instead. this should remove any hidden spaces/characters after the email.

```
Email.matches
    ("([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}).*"))
```

according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html

> public boolean matches (String regularExpression)
>
> Added in API level 1 Tests whether this string matches the given
>   regularExpression. This method returns true only if the regular
>   expression matches the entire input string. A common mistake is to
>   assume that this method behaves like contains(CharSequence); if you
>   want to match anywhere within the input string, you need to add .* to
>   the beginning and end of your regular expression. See matches(String,
>   CharSequence).

Comment: @Michelle, can you do a Log.d("TAG", "-->" + Email +"<--" ); just before the matches call? then filter by "TAG".

Comment: How do I filter by "TAG"?

Comment: @Michelle you can do filtering like the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio