# Android logcat is flooded with "W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op"

Tags: android, google-maps

When I drag Maps on activity having Google Maps fragment, my logcat is flooded with

> "W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op".

Google Maps version build.gradle (app):

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'`

Comment: it happens with 9.2.0 too. you can right click on the line and hit 'fold lines like this' (remove timestamp etc).

Comment: Same here, anyone??

Comment: It is not play services version problem. I had version 8.4.0 and I got this problem, so I updated version to 9.2.1 but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: have you found the cause?

Comment: I think it is spawned by the new play services 9.4.52  on the device.

Comment: I'm on Play Services 8.1.0 and have been for awhile now. A couple days ago I started getting the same flood of logcat warnings.

Comment: I am facing this too .. also the map looks weirder now .. anyone face that too? Some roads have become thin lines and theres a greenish tinge in the map ..

Comment: Is there any actual problem? I don't understand this question at all? Why does it have a bounty? What isn't working? You do know that you can filter out log messages you don't care about, right?

Comment: Issues posted https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10201 in bug google play services

Comment: Update: They have fixed the issue and the fix will be released in the next Google Play Services release

According to them: The log message does not indicate any problem, so you can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**UPDATE (26th September 2016):**
I just checked the fix in play-services-maps **9.6.1**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
```

The issue 10201 is [closed](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10201#c26) and release notes [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#september_21_2016)

---

I think its a render time log. No connection with java code. I also have same log. and i feel its cause by : **SupportMapFragment** in xml file. When i touch Map, GL render layout and prints this log.

It is inside Map Library. So we can't modify it. but i think sometimes it cause memory overload. and so system calls GC to dump memory.

It's just a warning. So ignore it for now. but it should be fix by Google map library maker.

Edition (1st August, 2016) : now its a known issue and will be solve in next Google Play Library release. [ref](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10201)

Edition (2nd August, 2016) : got an update to play-services-maps as **9.2.1 -> 9.4.0**, but warning message still there.

Edition (5th August, 2016) : the fix is not in 9.4 but will be in an upcoming release [ref](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10201#c13)

Note : for hide bunch of same messages i found one trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585818).

Comment: The fix is not in this build (9.4.0), but will be included in upcoming release. [link](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10201)

Comment: The fix is not in this build (9.6.0) also, warning messages still exist.

Comment: Error messages do not appear in 9.6.1

Answer (score 25):

You can add to following regex, `^((?!GLHudOverlay).)*$`, to your logcat filter to hide the message, but as the accepted answer states this is a bug with Google so the best we can hope for is a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks for this it was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Or right click the logcat message (In AndroidStudio) and select "Fold Lines Like This", click edit, and delete everything but the message.