# Showing empty google map fragment in blue color in android tabbed activity

Tags: android, google-maps

It shows output as `W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op` altough the code used in current app has worked earliar in another app with same code. 
note: The API is not same for both

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522352/android-logcat-is-flooded-with-w-google-maps-android-api-glhudoverlay-deprecat

Answer (score 0):

That is the reason, I have the same issue. Just make checkSelfPermission and see if that works. if not you must realize that code can't work in your api. [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: My problem is solved. The blue screen representing  ocean. so i have changed 'mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(hyderabad));mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));' to 'mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hyderabad,12.0f));'. Now map showing my Hyderabad 'LatLng hyderabad = new LatLng(17.3850,78.4867);'. But my logcat is filled with 'W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op'. This issue will be solved by google play services for the next release [https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10201]. Thank you