# android studio logcat: hide irrelevant messages

Tags: android-logcat, android-studio-2.3

Android studio: there are many messages in logcat, which are not related to the app I am debugging. How to prevent them from showing up in logcat?

```
08-18 19:33:00.004 1538-1554/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
08-18 19:33:00.030 1538-1554/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
08-18 19:33:00.078 1538-1554/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
08-18 19:33:00.143 1538-1554/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
08-18 19:33:00.171 1538-1554/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
08-18 19:33:01.175 1333-6343/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
08-18 19:33:01.175 1333-6343/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
08-18 19:33:06.211 1333-1333/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
08-18 19:33:06.211 1333-1333/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
08-18 19:33:11.240 1333-6343/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
08-18 19:33:11.241 1333-6343/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
08-18 19:33:16.278 1333-3720/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
08-18 19:33:16.278 1333-3720/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter logcat in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Usually at the top of the logcat window, there's a few dropdowns.  From left to right (for me, anyway), one for the device, one for the process, one for the permitted level of the logs, and one for the...kind of filtering, I guess?  Make sure that the process dropdown has selected the process you're debugging, and that the kind-of-filtering dropdown has "Show only selected application" selected.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Android Studio, you can set the filter:

```
package:mine
```

Then you should only see messages generated from within your app.

If I recall, it is there by default, but you may have deleted it by accident along with another filter.