# Android Studio 3.1 not showing logs properly

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

I am using Android Studio 3.1 for Android Development and it is not showing logs properly.
See the image below for more details:

[image]

In the above screenshot i am currently running app on an emulator. Only 2 lines in the logs are of the app that is running on the emulator. If i run the application on physical device, results are same.

I was also facing this problem on Android Studio 3.0 and earlier.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the granularity of the filter, this can be done from [image: editing filter]. [image: the logcat filter]

Enter the configuration in the dialog.

There is also option of "Fold lines like this" on the logs. You just need to right click and select.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio) explains both configuration in detail.