# Android LogCat Logging way too much stuff

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

Android Logcat is logging way too much stuff on real device and sometimes the emulator.

My Settings are: `Show only selected application` but then it says above `No Debuggable Applications`.

The Log Level is currently on `Debug`

Here is an example:

```
05-29 04:53:36.173      414-464/? I/WifiHW﹕ CMD: SIGNAL_POLL
05-29 04:53:36.193      414-464/? I/WifiHW﹕ REPLY: RSSI=-50
05-29 04:53:36.193      414-464/? I/WifiHW﹕ REPLY: LINKSPEED=65
05-29 04:53:36.193      414-464/? I/WifiHW﹕ REPLY: NOISE=9999
05-29 04:53:36.193      414-464/? I/WifiHW﹕ REPLY: FREQUENCY=0
05-29 04:53:36.223      414-427/? E/Sensors﹕ pjn=== LightSensor, als_value:50.000000
05-29 04:53:36.483      414-427/? E/Sensors﹕ pjn=== LightSensor, als_value:51.000000
05-29 04:53:36.743      414-427/? E/Sensors﹕ pjn=== LightSensor, als_value:50.000000
05-29 04:53:36.873      414-427/? E/Sensors﹕ pjn=== LightSensor, als_value:51.000000
05-29 04:53:37.003      414-427/? E/Sensors﹕ pjn=== LightSensor, als_value:50.000000
05-29 04:53:37.133      414-427/? E/Sensors﹕ pjn=== LightSensor, als_value:51.000000
```

Comment: possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806484/real-device-produce-too-many-log)

Comment: Related posts - [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6854127/465053) & [How to filter logcat in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19931987/465053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it says `No Debuggable Applications`:

[Article Answered on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593927/android-studio-no-debuggable-applications)

```
You also should have Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration active.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Apps you will have something like :

```
Log.v(TAG, "Test");
```

**For Android Studio:**

In your Logcat filter, type in what you have for `TAG`

**For Eclipse:**

In your Logcat filter, type in what you have for `TAG` preceded by `tag:`

For example:
`tag:MY_TAG`

Comment: how about multiple tags? he should do filter base on the package name or use one of the answers above

Comment: For what it is worth, the question never asks about multiple tags. Just that they want to reduce the clutter in logcat. Using appropriate tags is a great way of reducing clutter in logcat. I don't think a downvote is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Got the final solution here.

If android studio shows that

> No Debuggable Applications

Then there must be a dropDown list nearby.

Next, choose the application you desire to see it's logs in the dropDown list.

And the idle logs will just disappear finally.

[image]