# Android device create too many logs

Tags: android, eclipse

for unknown reason my phone create too many logs without any application tag.
it's so rapidly that my own app's log wont last more than 2 second.
someone has already asked but nobody has answered yet.
[Real device produce too many log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806484/real-device-produce-too-many-log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you gotta cancel all the background process that are running in you device, and some logs which you have mentioned are general log which will be constantly running in all the android device

Answer (score 0):

Select show only selected application. [Check this android developer resource](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)