# Filter application specific logs in adb logcat. (log tag, log message, pid, package name)

Tags: android, adb, logcat, pid, android-logcat

I'm taking logcat using this command:

```
C:\abs\adb logcat >> "Testdata".txt
```

This is collecting all logs happening on device.

But I want to take only "Application specific" logs, can anyone please help me with that?

I know we can create filter in DDMS but, those filter value will erase after some time, and I want to take it using adb.

Comment: package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26257852/1778421

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: adb logcat -s "YOURTAG" >> "Testdata".txt

Comment: Thanks a lot, Also if I want to take logs by filtering "log message" (not log tag), What will be my command ?

Comment: With grep command: adb logcat | grep --invert-match 'log message'. I don't know if it will work...