# Android ADB command to get the application specific log in command prompt of windows

Tags: android, adb

Hi i want to get the application specific log in the command prompt of windows i tried this

[Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

```
adb -d logcat com.mycompanyname.demoapp:I *:S
```

But didn't work for me huge log was printing which was very difficult for me to find my app specific log.

I want to print my app specific log in command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string that `logcat` uses for filtering by is not a *package name* but a [TAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

So `logcat com.mycompanyname.demoapp:*` won't work unless the package was compiled with its name used as the logging tag.

There is a workaround you can use with Android 7.0+ devices:

```
adb shell "logcat --pid=$(pidof -s com.mycompanyname.demoapp)"
```

This command finds out the *process ID* for the package and then uses it for `logcat` filtering.

Comment: so how to filtter  by package name