# How to gracefully stop tcpdump process on a phone?

Tags: android, python, automation, subprocess, adb

I am trying to automate fetching network logs from an Android device to Windows system. For that purpose I need to send multiple commands. I am able to club most of them, but now I got stuck where I have to stop the `tcpdump` process and copy the capture file from the device using `adb pull`.

I am using this command to start `tcpdump`:

```
adb shell su -c ./data/tcpdump -i any -s 0 -w /sdcard/Download/tcpdump.pcap
```

Manually running the above command works fine, so I assume the following `python` code is also good:

```
self._proc3 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=PIPE ,stderr=PIPE)
```

For stopping the process, I have tried multiple approaches like:

Sending ctrl-c , `\x03\n`, all in `Popen`. Also, killing the subrocess using `taskill`. However, nothing works. The capture file is not getting created. I don't know whether this is due to some Windows limitation or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Please make meaningful titles for your questions. In your post you reasonably described a problem with not being able to properly stop the `tcpdump` capture process - but the title did not make any sense.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622698/1778421

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the `SIGINT` signal to the `tcpdump` process.

Depending on busybox/toolbox/toybox versions available the following would make all running `tcpdump` instances to stop capturing and dump the log:

```
adb shell su -c killall -q -2 tcpdump
```