# Script to stop logcat in terminal window

Tags: python, scripting, adb, logcat

I currently have a python script that launches an iTerm window and runs logcat on an android device. When what I am doing in the script is complete, I want to also have the ability to stop the logcat. I was originally just killing iTerm to stop the log, but this will not work going forward...is there anyway to programatically stop the log? (this is typically done by pressing ctr+c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622698/1778421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adb shell killall -2 logcat` would gracefully stop all running `logcat` processes on the device.