# Bash shell script command executes out of order when run through Bitrise

Tags: bash, adb, bitrise

In the bitrise workflow's script step, I added following snippet:

```
adb shell ps | grep screenrecord | awk ‘{print $2}’ | xargs adb shell kill
```

Purpose is to kill the process called *screenrecord* that was started in a previous step and it works fine when I test it on my system. But when this workflow is triggered through bitrise, it fails with following logs:

[image: Bitrise Logs]

What is the cause of this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: A common bug is when `grep` matches itself. The ngrep` here is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) anyway; `pidof screenrecord` or if you don't have that `ps | awk '/[s]creenrecord/ { print $2 }' | xargs -r kill`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622698/1778421

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because `awk` is not outputting the process id. One possible workaround to try is the following:

```
adb shell ps | grep screenrecord | sed -E 's/[ ]+/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs adb shell kill
```

where the `awk` command has been substituted with `sed` (to remove the multiple spaces) and a `cut` one (to get the process id).