# Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked a lot, but none of the solutions proposed worked for me

Since I started my project, my LogCat has been displaying just enough information about my app. But somehow (I don't remember changing any settings), it is now displaying too many information. And It makes it impossible to detect my Log messages.

The problem is I don't use My appName as TAG for most of these Logs. I used my methods names to detect my messages. Wish makes the following solution not appropriate in my case : `adb logcat -s "MyAppName"`

I tried the filters proposed by eclipse, but none of them makes it look like it used to be !

Do you guys happen to know any other solution ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is quite easy : in the `logcat` view click the **side menu** button : it makes filters appear on the left.

[image]

you can add filters by cliking the '+' sign and add yout application package identifier as filter.

set the name you want for your filter :

[image]

you can also filter by log levels, tags etc...