# Logcat shows all processes Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

Im trying to 'debug' my application, but for some reason, 'LogCat' shows all processes that is running on my phone, so it's imposible to do some proper 'debuging'. It worked before, so i suspect that i changed a setting or something by mistake.

I have tryed to choose just my application under the device im debuging on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Filter in LogCat Application name should have your package name.

Like following.

[image]