# Error: WAMP server and Android application?

Tags: php, android, mysql, wamp

I am attempting to run an open source application on my computer that connects an android application to a WAMP server.

This application definitely works as a colleague of mine can run it on their computer. However, I cannot get it to run on mine.

The following code is from an activity that attempts to register a user so they can then log in. However I get a logcat error when I attempt to run it. What is the issue?

I have connected my WAMP server correctly (Icon is green) and also created the database within MYSQL. I know that this is working as I can populate the MYSQL database from a PHP script. However I cannot seem to connect it to an android application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried all that I can think of in order to solve it.

**Logcat Error report 1:**

```
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 1355
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:109)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     ... 4 more
```

Logcat error 2:

```
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 1355
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:109)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-24 13:41:17.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     ... 4 more
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mysqltest.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52906bd4 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.onPreExecute(Register.java:86)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at com.example.mysqltest.Register.onClick(Register.java:68)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-24 13:41:17.699: E/WindowManager(1355):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Android activity:**

```
public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button  mRegister;

     // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script

    //localhost :  
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
   // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/register.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.56.1/webservice/register.php";

  //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/register.php";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new CreateUser().execute();

    }

    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script 
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());                
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

**Corresponding PHP script:**

```
<?php

/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.inc.php");

//if posted data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //If the username or password is empty when the user submits
    //the form, the page will die.
    //Using die isn't a very good practice, you may want to look into
    //displaying an error message within the form instead.  
    //We could also do front-end form validation from within our Android App,
    //but it is good to have a have the back-end code do a double check.
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {


        // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please Enter Both a Username and Password.";

        //die will kill the page and not execute any code below, it will also
        //display the parameter... in this case the JSON data our Android
        //app will parse
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    //if the page hasn't died, we will check with our database to see if there is
    //already a user with the username specificed in the form.  ":user" is just
    //a blank variable that we will change before we execute the query.  We
    //do it this way to increase security, and defend against sql injections
    $query        = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :user";
    //now lets update what :user should be
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username']
    );

    //Now let's make run the query:
    try {
        // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    //fetch is an array of returned data.  If any data is returned,
    //we know that the username is already in use, so we murder our
    //page
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("This username is already in use");

        //You could comment out the above die and use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    //If we have made it here without dying, then we are in the clear to 
    //create a new user.  Let's setup our new query to create a user.  
    //Again, to protect against sql injects, user tokens such as :user and :pass
    $query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( :user, :pass ) ";

    //Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':pass' => $_POST['password']
    );

    //time to run our query, and create the user
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    //If we have made it this far without dying, we have successfully added
    //a new user to our database.  We could do a few things here, such as 
    //redirect to the login page.  Instead we are going to echo out some
    //json data that will be read by the Android application, which will login
    //the user (or redirect to a different activity, I'm not sure yet..)
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);

    //for a php webservice you could do a simple redirect and die.
    //header("Location: login.php"); 
    //die("Redirecting to login.php");


} else {
?>
    <h1>Register</h1> 
    <form action="register.php" method="post"> 
        Username:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        Password:<br /> 
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Register New User" /> 
    </form>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Logcat error:

```
07-24 19:16:30.584: E/BandwidthController(155): runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -A bw_raw_PREROUTING -m owner --socket-exists
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554): problem enabling bandwidth controls
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554): com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector$NativeDaemonFailureException: command '1 bandwidth enable' failed with '400 1 Bandwidth command failed'
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:391)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.executeForList(NativeDaemonConnector.java:327)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:292)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.prepareNativeDaemon(NetworkManagementService.java:348)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.systemReady(NetworkManagementService.java:224)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.ServerThread$2.run(SystemServer.java:961)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady(ActivityManagerService.java:9363)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:938)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1179)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-24 19:16:30.584: A/NetworkManagementService(554):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 19:16:30.588: E/WifiStateMachine(554): Failed to reload STA firmware java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: command '2 softap fwreload eth1 STA' failed with '501 2 SoftAP command has failed'
```

Comment: did you make sure on your computer the login ip is the same ? this might be different http://192.168.56.1/webservice/register.php as that was his local ip and yours might be different...

Comment: no, i changed the IP address that he had, the one that you see there is mine

Comment: and if you hit that url from your browser its reachable ?

Comment: If I do so I get the error:

Comment: Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: what password do you use to login to mysql with your root user, is it YES ?

Comment: theres some config file that has those credentials for the mysql db and your mysql db doesnt have that

Comment: i dont know try leaving blank

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your database credentials. Check in your config file what password is being specified for root, and make sure it is the same as what you are using locally.

Comment: My config file has the following: $username = "root"; 
    $password = " "; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "rosslocalhost1";

Comment: What do I need to compare these against? Thanks for your help!

Comment: make sure theres a db name rosslocalhost1, and use the right login, so if your mysql root users pw is YES make it YES in your config file

Comment: Im almost sure that mySql root user doesnt have a password, how can I check this? thanks

Comment: I thought you said you were using password yes or something

Comment: this doesnt give any results for me?

Comment: ok how are you accessing your mysql installation ? are you using a gui like workbench? or command line ??

Comment: ok are you connecting to a database called rosslocalhost1 ? and if so what credentials are you connecting with?

Comment: Yes my database is called rosslocalhost1, the host is localhost, user is called called roost and the password is empty?

Comment: im asking you lol what is that what you are using ? didnt you have to configure the database ?

Comment: Yeah sorry i didnt mean the question mark, that is the details of the db

Comment: and its roost or root ?

Comment: ok so if that's working then your app you should run right ? because you told me in an earlier comment that you were getting this error:
Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 

you were using password YES now that they are both the same in the config and the your database what happens when you run app what error do you get ?

Comment: I dont think I was using the password "YES" what script was this in? Sorry to confuse you

Comment: no not a problem just trying to help, umm I thought thats what you meant look under the comments of your question. So what error do you get now ?

Comment: Please see my edit (at bottom)it show the error i am now getting in logcat

Comment: Not all Logcat messages are yours. Each entry has a TAG field and an application field. Use filters to hide log output that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: but that message is from my logcat putput?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android

to filter