# What best way to CONSTANTLY disable specific lines in logcat in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I use Eclipse and watch logcat console.

Periodically I see follow lines from another app (this is example):

```
09-23 10:13:12.437: I/wpa_supplicant(17725): wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
```

or

```
09-23 10:13:17.223: E/Parcel(350): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
```

or

```
09-23 10:13:31.858: I/BatteryService(916): start UEvent update, event = {SUBSYSTEM=power_supply, DEVPATH=/devices/platform/msm_ssbi.0/pm8038-core/pm8921-charger/power_supply/battery, POWER_SUPPLY_HEALTH=Good, POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Charging, POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion, POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=1739000, POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=3200000, POWER_SUPPLY_TEMP=327, POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1, POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=battery, POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=949126, POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_MAX=2217772, POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=44, POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MAX_DESIGN=4200000, SEQNUM=147831, POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=-320900, POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=3873819, ACTION=change, POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_TYPE=Fast}
```

or etc.

I can disable show this lines by filter in console. But this operation I must be doing every time when restart Eclipse or reopen logcat console.

What is best way CONSTANTLY disable showing that lines in logcat in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto your logcat, and add required filter to diplay on those logs which are you only concerned of,

read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Or in you logact,  press green + sign, set the required values

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can filter all the logcat messages with the help of TAGs specified by you.

- Use a specific tag for your logcat results.
- Create a filter inside logcat which filters that specific tag only.

  - To add a filter open Logcat and press the green <kbd>+</kbd> button.
    [image]
  - this will show a dialog like this [image: Creating logcat filters]

You can also create filters for specific package names.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in tag filter,

add/remove TAG name like "** wpa_supplicant**" this will disable log for ** wpa_supplicant**

tag:^(?!Choreographer|BatteryService|Parcel|wpa_supplicant).*$