# Android: How to determine if Google Play Services was correctly installed

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I'm building an Android app using Eclipse on OS X. I've been through numerous tutorials on adding Google Play Services to my app. I believe I've installed it correctly. However, I'm having issues with Admob ads and I think it might be related to Google Play Services.

**How can I determine if Google Play Services was correctly installed?**

I didn't see anything in the terminal when I tried:

```
./adb logcat | grep -i googleplay
```

Comment: I think this will post will help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link for Google play services setup and verification

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/google-play-services-setup.html

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. Include information from the link in your answer to prevent link rot.