# Android: List of ADB logcat/shell (filter-spec/commands) available

Tags: android, logging, adb

Where can i find list of ADB logcat filter-spec options.

Adb command shows adb logcat [ < filter-spec > ] - View device log.

Ex: "adb logcat -v time -b radio -s RILJ

Could not find much info in Dev doc reference.

Want more commands like "radio ", ex network,power,audio.

Thanks
Nitz

Comment: http://codeadapter.blogspot.in/2014/10/adb-commands.html

Comment: @DonChakkappan good link but does not cover all i suppose.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android