# How can I stop my app from crashing when trying to make a GET request with an ASyncTask?

Tags: java, android, get

I am really confused as to why I am having this problem. I am very new to android development so I am not really sure where to start when solving this problem. I have all the required permissions in the manifest file. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`.

When a button is pressed `myClickHandler` is called and creates a URL with the two `EditText`'s. After it does that it calls `downloadWebPageTask` which starts an ASyncTask. This AsyncTank takes the URL and then sends GET request. Here is my code.

```
public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    SetText url = new SetText();
    String stringUrl = url.createURL(artist_text.getText().toString(), release_text.getText().toString());
    new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
}

public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        //SendStuff send = new SendStuff("mrblahblahblacksheep");
        //return send.sendGet(urls[0]);
        String url = urls[0];
        String final_response = "FAILED!";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);

            final_response = response.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return final_response;
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        result_text.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Every time I press the button in the Emulator the app crashes. None of the crash data is saved in the logcat so I am unsure as to wear to find out the reasons for the crash.

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to narrow down the issue?

Comment: Just did that. It is when the application trys to send the GET request that it crashes. So when it sends `response  = client.execute(request)`

Comment: Is `result_text` initialized somewhere?

Comment: `result_text` is initialized. It is not shown in the code block

Comment: Logcat `urls` and `final_response` plz

Comment: Maybe not the reason of your problem, but `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly the problem:

```
response = client.execute(request);
final_response = response.toString();
```

If response is null, then `response.toString()` will throw NPE and your app will crash.

Make error handling graceful.

Try returning `null` result from catch blocks when you encounter exceptions. Also, for NPEs make if-else blocks and return `null` explicitly.

In `onPostExecute(...)` check if result is null, then display some default text or else display expected result.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the problem. The app crashes before `response.toString()` is set.

Comment: I tried `new DownloadWebpageTask().execute("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3/");` it works for me perfectly. Unless we know what URL you are using its very hard to pinpoint the issue. Could you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android to get logs for your app. Also, what device and OS you are using.