# Application gets installed but not launching and still logcat continuously increasing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I am new to android development. I am developing an application, everything was working fine but now when I click on run, application gets installed in phone but it is not launching. Even when my app is not running, android studio logcat continuously goes on increasing and the logs increase very fast so that I cannot see the errors by scrolling up. I copied the logs at an instant and pasted in text editor and checked for errors but I am not able to identify anything from it. Some strange messages about the other apps of phone which I am not able to understand. Can anyone tell what could be the reason for this? And how can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need any further details  of code or logcat etc.

Comment: change the log level to error

Comment: Look up on how to filter the logcat to a specific application. Those logs that "scroll very fast" are logs for the whole system, and are not very useful when tracking bugs in an application.

Comment: Try putting log messages in onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() of your main activity... Change the log level to more strict level... Also does your app works in IDE simulator ? If yes than check the supported API version and the device api verison in which you are trying to run app.

Comment: You should filter the logcat that only display your app's log for tracing why your app didn't start. You can check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android) to know how to filter the logcat in Android Studio.

Comment: In my logcat window log level is verbose and it is showing only for default application. It was working fine before. I added some code in ananother activity different than mainactivity of the project and when I clicked on run it showed random logs( I think they are random because I didn't find any link of them with the application ) and they go on increasing, they never stop. I cannot scroll up and read the error messages from the logcat because they are too fast in showing up. I have changed the log level to error but still no errors in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the issue

> Too much output to process

or the logcat logs is increasing very-fast,then consider changing the USB data cable.I faced the same issue on S5-mini, but changing the data-cable solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one launcher activity in your **Androidmanifest.xml**, i guess you have missed same.If **MainActivity** is launcher activity for you, it should look like below

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: hmm.. not actually, i suspect he would have deleted it by mistake

Comment: Nope, MainActivity is still LAUNCHER activity. I haven't deleted anything.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a beginner. Can you explain how to do it?