# logcat spammed of error messages having nothing to do with my app

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Whenever I,m using android studio to run my app, the logcat get spammed with unrelated messages such as :

```
E/SMD﹕ DCD OFF

E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 1745

E/dalvikvm
```

Is there a way to prevent it to be displayed on the logcat? The logcat get properly unreadable and prevents me to see the crash report of my app properly.

This is happening while using my own device to debug ( Samsung S3 mini ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw you can filter it with your package name in process tag

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira how? I have to admit that I'm not expert on linux and adb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android

Comment: I used the tag of the app as a filter and it seems that it works. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend you use filter, you can set your keyword, like if you use system.out.println() in your app, you enter this syntax as keyword, then you will get a list of all content related with this syntax.