# Real-time viewing of logging Android App

Tags: logcat

I need an App that shows in real-time the LogCat output for a specific App that is running on the device at that moment.

With aLogCat I only view the system-wide messages, but I need to see the Log.d("test","test") messages of my own App.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Not that way, from android 4.x and up you need root access for that, apps are allowed only to read their own logs. You either need to have root acces to enable the logcat viewer app to show all logcat messages or you need to connect to your device through adb and retrieve the log from there. There are a large number of tools available to do log analysis, you can use androidstudio or eclipse or better an external logcat viewer. There are a large number of such viewers available like tailexpert or mlogcat, which give you more power tools like filtering and highlighting to increase log readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter messages for specific app in logcat, for that you have to give the package name also while logging.

Referred from this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854182/6849996): `Log.<log level>("<your package name>", "message");`

Another solution is to use some [realtime logging tools like this](https://webfirmframework.binpress.com/product/realtime-logging-web-app-for-android-iphone-mobiles-any-devices/4731) but there also you have to send log message to the tool in the app. So both solutions require modification in the app!