# how to print logs in cmd console while execute android instrument test

Tags: android, testing, logging, printing, cmd

I open a cmd on windows system, and then input "`adb shell am instrument -w com.demo.uia.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`" to run android test.

I want to print log in the cmd while run the test, can anyone tell me how to write code to print log? I have tied `system.out.println("xx")` and `Log.i("xx","xx")`, but it's useless.

I want to show the log in cmd line, not in logcat.
I solved the problem now, use sendStatus api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Comment: I want to show the log in the cmd console, not logcat.

Comment: I solved the problem now, use sendStatus api.

Comment: Can you answer your question showing how you did it?

Answer (score 10):

I guess @MoMo did something like this to have logging output in command prompt window:

In your test class define a function:

```
private void out(String str) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString(Instrumentation.REPORT_KEY_STREAMRESULT, "\n" + str);
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().sendStatus(0, b);
}
```

Then simply use it in @Test functions like:

```
out("Some message...");
```

The output appears when running the test in Command Prompt window with *adb shell am instrument...*, but it is not shown in Run window of Android Studio. It somehow filters the output of test runs, and I cannot find a setting to modify this filter.

Comment: I've managed to run instrumentation tests via the command line but using gradle i.e.g, `./gradlew :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -P android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.testingstuff.ExampleInstrumentedTest#what`
However, your solution doesn't work out with it!