# Where do the logs go when I try to log in an Instrumented Unit Test in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-junit

I've followed this documentation to create an Instrumented Test Unit class: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html#run

But when I try to use logs or System.out.println as part of my test method, none of the logs show up anywhere.

Comment: This answer appears to at least offer one way to get stuff back to the console. Nothing else worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41861620/449722