# Missing Logcat options?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I need to create a new filter. However, there is usually more than options that I have in logcat. What happened to the "show only selected application" button in order to edit the filter configuration? And how do I get it back?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/acLUx.png

Comment: Just to confirm, is this the button [you're looking for?](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20220713175648/selectpackagename.png)

Comment: The one on the far right.

Comment: Then [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735128/15749574) might help?

Comment: No, that is only for issues with the already existing button. I don't even have it as an option to use, which I need.

Comment: Just write `package:mine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I throught there is some logcat change after android studio upgrade.

If you only want show by tag, you can use such as `tag=:android.geoqui` in filter.

More infomation in https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat.