# Hundreds of random errors in logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I'm experiencing a strange error in logcat when I work on my project.

These errors just keep coming and coming and coming that I can feel the "wagon-wheel" effect in the logcat.

Errors are:

```
    2019-01-03 17:08:11.545 20877-20877/? E/HotwordDetector: Invalid or incompatible speaker models. Silent enrollment required.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing hotword data buffer
            at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordData.nativeNew(Native Method)
            at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordData.<init>(SourceFile:4)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.microdetection.a.a.a.b(SourceFile:10)
            at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.a(SourceFile:52)
            at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.at(SourceFile:35)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.a.dIB(SourceFile:48)
            at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.b.handleMessage(SourceFile:4)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
    2019-01-03 17:08:11.559 20877-20877/? E/SpeechMicro: PIE support is disabled.
   2019-01-03 17:11:38.350 20877-20877/? E/HotwordDetector: Invalid or incompatible speaker models. Silent enrollment required.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing hotword data buffer
        at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordData.nativeNew(Native Method)
        at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordData.<init>(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.microdetection.a.a.a.b(SourceFile:10)
        at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.a(SourceFile:52)
        at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.at(SourceFile:35)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.a.dIB(SourceFile:48)
        at com.google.android.voiceinteraction.GsaVoiceInteractionService.dIB(SourceFile:109)
        at com.google.android.voiceinteraction.l.onServiceConnected(SourceFile:69)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1579)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1607)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
2019-01-03 17:11:38.351 20877-20877/? E/GsaVoiceInteractionSrv: Failed to perform next action.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing hotword data buffer
        at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordData.nativeNew(Native Method)
        at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordData.<init>(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.microdetection.a.a.a.b(SourceFile:10)
        at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.a(SourceFile:52)
        at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.at(SourceFile:35)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.a.dIB(SourceFile:48)
        at com.google.android.voiceinteraction.GsaVoiceInteractionService.dIB(SourceFile:109)
        at com.google.android.voiceinteraction.l.onServiceConnected(SourceFile:69)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1579)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1607)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Neither I am able to stop it nor I am able to find the actual errors of app if any. It's like a needle in haystack(though I can search).

Please provide a solution to eliminate these errors if any.

Comment: this your Error parsing hotword data buffer

Comment: [Then This will help you I think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Answer (score 5):

In logcat you can filter log by your own application, please select `"Show only selected app"` filter near Regex in your logcat.

It will show only your application logs.

[image]

Comment: Its by default Show Only selected App

Comment: No Filters is the default value.

Comment: Now as you have mentioned, I have selected the "show only selected app" filter option from that dropdown and it's only showing my app's errors but with different PID which means I've to select my dead app from dropdown to look for errors. Any solution for that?

Comment: I don't think as a problem. @Hardik. In case your app crashes, just don't touch the "crash dialog" on device, so your logcat stays in place.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for helping out but I've found the solution to eliminate the errors.

The errors were related to Google app which was trying to listen to hotword "Ok Google" continuously to work, so after I denied this app the permssion of Microphone, the errors are now limited to this one line:

```
E: openRecord() permission denied: recording not allowed
```

Comment: I also have this error. can you please tell me how did you denied that permission?