# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid speaker model provided

Tags: android

I'm developing app in android and for some reason I'm receiving this error.

I did not change any code line and suddenly I'm getting this error.
I have no idea what should i do, its not even pointing where the problem is.

**LOG**

```
02-22 20:22:42.884 4637-4637/? E/HotwordDetector: Invalid or incompatible speaker models. Silent enrollment required.
                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid speaker model provided
                                                      at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordRecognizer.nativeNew(Native Method)
                                                      at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordRecognizer.<init>(SourceFile:6)
                                                      at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.a(SourceFile:65)
                                                      at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.as(SourceFile:35)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.a.esf(SourceFile:48)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.b.handleMessage(SourceFile:4)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
02-22 20:22:42.907 4637-4637/? E/HotwordDetector: Invalid or incompatible speaker models. Silent enrollment required.
                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid speaker model provided
                                                      at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordRecognizer.nativeNew(Native Method)
                                                      at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordRecognizer.<init>(SourceFile:6)
                                                      at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.a(SourceFile:65)
                                                      at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.as(SourceFile:35)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.a.esf(SourceFile:48)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.b.handleMessage(SourceFile:4)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
02-22 20:22:42.929 4637-4637/? E/HotwordDetector: Invalid or incompatible speaker models. Silent enrollment required.
                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid speaker model provided
                                                      at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordRecognizer.nativeNew(Native Method)
                                                      at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordRecognizer.<init>(SourceFile:6)
                                                      at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.a(SourceFile:65)
                                                      at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.k.as(SourceFile:35)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.a.esf(SourceFile:48)
                                                      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.b.handleMessage(SourceFile:4)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any idea why is it crashing?

Answer (score 0):

AudioRecord is not initialized, its null, you can see e in the first line

```
02-22 20:22:42.863 4637-5379/? E/AudioProvider: AudioRecord is null, can't start recording
```

Comment: I saw this, but its strange because i never used AudioRecord. I dont know where it is come from

Comment: investigate the error by the cell model, may be missing some permission for that cell

Comment: I added the permission but its still crash. I cant understand where it is come from

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021659/hundreds-of-random-errors-in-logcat

Answer (score 0):

Their is some mistake in layout/.xml file i.e designing part, check that properly.
In my case i got it because i was VerticalViewPager in main activity but in xml i passed it as viewpager.