# How do I update manifest to use com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, android-support-library

My Unity project uses:
1) Camerashot plugin which uses android-support-v4.jar
2) Firebase which uses com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0.aar

I cannot compile as these 2 libs conflict.
I must keep com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0.aar for Firebase.
When I remove android-support-v4.jar I am able to compile but the Camerashot does not work.

The mafinfest for Camershot shows:

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.Yellows.cameratest.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Here is a link to the entire Unity test project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p4a4FV5pFZfh_xZco7-JeiwM7Oj0Q42m

How do I update the provider to use the Firebase referenced lib com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0.aar and get this working?

Comment: Can you provide a logcat with any runtime errors you might be experiencing?

If you're not used to capturing these with Unity, I typically make sure I make a debug build. Then I open Android Studio, and select the project I want to debug from the dropdown. It doesn't matter _which_ project you have open, just that you have something open.

Comment: If you installed Android Studio with Unity, you can find `adb` in `platform-tools` (ex: `/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.5f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools`), and either `./adb logcat` from that directory or follow this tutorial to locate your package ID: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9869609/3043663